# What is the difference between JOIN and UNION?

Tags: sql, database, join, union

What is the difference between `JOIN` and `UNION`? Can I have an example?

Comment: Any modern DBS, like [MariaDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB), implements a UNION JOIN command. This is an [SQL&nbsp;3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:1999) command, but it isn't well known or used. Do learn more on *[UNION JOIN](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/union-join/)*.

Comment: @Auston UNION JOIN was proposed but never added to SQL.

Answer (score 411, accepted):

`UNION` puts lines from queries after each other, while `JOIN` makes a cartesian product and subsets it -- completely different operations. Trivial example of `UNION`:

```
mysql> SELECT 23 AS bah
    -> UNION
    -> SELECT 45 AS bah;
+-----+
| bah |
+-----+
|  23 | 
|  45 | 
+-----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

similary trivial example of `JOIN`:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM 
    -> (SELECT 23 AS bah) AS foo 
    -> JOIN 
    -> (SELECT 45 AS bah) AS bar
    -> ON (33=33);
+-----+-----+
| foo | bar |
+-----+-----+
|  23 |  45 | 
+-----+-----+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: @Alex Martelli's answer was almost perfect if it's not too succinct by relying on the concept of Cartesian product (of which I had to look up to understand what it meant)

Comment: Let me just...upvote this beautiful masterpiece..there you go. Simplest way of explaining them.

Comment: It's the clear, simple examples that really hammer home the point, and by extension hammer home the value of good simple examples in general.

Answer (score 75):

[UNION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) combines the results of two or more queries into a single result set that includes all the rows that belong to all queries in the union.

By using [JOINs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517.aspx), you can retrieve data from two or more tables based on logical relationships between the tables. Joins indicate how SQL should use data from one table to select the rows in another table.

The UNION operation is different from using JOINs that combine columns from two tables.

UNION Example:

```
SELECT 1 AS [Column1], 2 AS [Column2]
UNION
SELECT 3 AS [Column1], 4 AS [Column2]
```

Output:

```
Column1    Column2
-------------------
1          2
3          4
```

JOIN Example:

```
SELECT a.Column1, b.Column2 FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.Id = b.AFKId
```

This will output all the rows from both the tables for which the condition `a.Id = b.AFKId` is true.

Comment: Join can retrieve data from one* or more tables. Not necessarily two

Answer (score 72):

You  may see the same schematic explanations for both, but these are totally confusing.

For UNION:

[image]

For JOIN:

[image]

Comment: These images imply that `FULL OUTER JOIN` is the same as `UNION`, which [do have differences](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cb8fed73-c134-46ef-aff8-7d4ea57a1033/difference-between-union-all-and-full-outer-join?forum=transactsql)

Comment: This answer points out that those images are confusing (which IMO they are) but then doesn't go on to explain why or offer any clarification towards the original question.

Comment: Each image with diagrams explains perfectly the situation. There is no single image than can merge all diagrams. That will be more confusing.

Answer (score 52):

### JOIN:

A join is used for displaying columns with the same or
different names from different tables. The output displayed
will have all the columns shown individually. That is, the
columns will be aligned next to each other.

### UNION:

The UNION set operator is used for combining data from two
tables which have columns with the same datatype.
When a UNION is performed the data from both tables will be
collected in a single column having the same datatype.

For example:

See the two tables shown below:

```
Table t1
Articleno article price manufacturer_id
1 hammer 3 $ 1
2 screwdriver 5 $ 2

Table t2
manufacturer_id manufacturer
1 ABC Gmbh
2 DEF Co KG
```

Now for performing a JOIN type the query is shown below.

```
SELECT articleno, article, manufacturer
FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON (t1.manufacturer_id =
t2.manufacturer_id);

articelno article manufacturer
1 hammer ABC GmbH
2 screwdriver DEF Co KG
```

That is a join.

UNION means that you have to tables or resultset with the
same amount and type of columns and you add this to
tables/resultsets together. Look at this example:

```
Table year2006
Articleno article price manufacturer_id
1 hammer 3 $ 1
2 screwdriver 5 $ 2

Table year2007
Articleno article price manufacturer_id
1 hammer 6 $ 3
2 screwdriver 7 $ 4

SELECT articleno, article, price, manufactruer_id
FROM year2006
UNION
SELECT articleno, article, price, manufacturer_id
FROM year2007

articleno article price manufacturer_id
1 hammer 3 $ 1
2 screwdriver 5 $ 2
1 hammer 6 $ 3
2 screwdriver 7 $ 4
```

Answer (score 27):

They're completely different things.

A [join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) allows you to relate similar data in different tables.

A union returns the results of two different queries as a single recordset.

Answer (score 16):

Union makes two queries look like one. Joins are for examining two or more tables in a single query statement

Answer (score 16):

Joins and unions can be used to combine data from one or more tables. The difference lies in how the data is combined.

In simple terms, joins combine data into new columns. If two tables are joined together, then the data from the first table is shown in one set of column alongside the second table’s column in the same row.

Unions combine data into new rows. If two tables are “unioned” together, then the data from the first table is in one set of rows, and the data from the second table in another set. The rows are in the same result.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that union will merge results ([SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) to be sure)(feature or bug?)

```
select 1 as id, 3 as value
union
select 1 as id, 3 as value
```

id,value

1,3

```
select * from (select 1 as id, 3 as value) t1 inner join (select 1 as id, 3 as value) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

id,value,id,value

1,3,1,3

Comment: This is according to the ANSI standard, UNION ALL does not merge the results

Comment: See also `UNION` vs `UNION ALL` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all

Answer (score 3):

1. The SQL JOIN clause is used to combine records from two or more tables in a database. A JOIN is a means for combining fields from two tables by using values common to each.
2. The SQL UNION operator combines the result of two or more SELECT statements.
   Each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns. The columns must also have similar data types. Also, the columns in each SELECT statement must be in the same order.

For example:
table 1 customers / table 2 orders

Inner join:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, AMOUNT, DATE
FROM CUSTOMERS 
INNER JOIN ORDERS 
ON CUSTOMERS.ID = ORDERS.CUSTOMER_ID;
```

Union:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, AMOUNT, DATE
 FROM CUSTOMERS 
LEFT JOIN ORDERS 
ON CUSTOMERS.ID = ORDERS.CUSTOMER_ID 
UNION
SELECT ID, NAME, AMOUNT, DATE
FROM CUSTOMERS 
RIGHT JOIN ORDERS 
ON CUSTOMERS.ID = ORDERS.CUSTOMER_ID;
```

Answer (score 2):

Union Operation is combined result of the **Vertical** Aggregate of the rows,
Join Operation is combined result of the **Horizontal** Aggregate of the Columns.

Comment: Did you mean JOIN in second part of the sentence?

Comment: @გენომუმლაძე yes it's Join in the later part of the answer and I have corrected it. Thank you for pointing :)

Answer (score 0):

The UNION operator is just for combining two or more SELECT statements.

While JOIN is for selecting rows from each table, either by the inner, outer, left or right method.

Refer to [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) . There is a better explanation with examples.

Answer (score 0):

Ussing UNION

UNION  is combines the results of two or more queries into a single result set that includes all the rows that belong to all queries in the union.

```
UNION Example:
SELECT 121 AS [Column1], 221 AS [Column2]
UNION
SELECT 321 AS [Column1], 422 AS [Column2]
```

```
Output:

Column1    Column2
-------------------
121          221
321          422
```

Ussing JOINs

JOINs, you can retrieve data from two or more tables based on logical relationships between the tables.

```
JOIN Example:
SELECT a.Column1, b.Column2 FROM TblA a INNER JOIN TblB b ON a.Id = b.id
```

Answer (score -1):

In the abstract, they are similar, in that two tables or result sets are being combined , but UNION is really for combining result sets with the SAME NUMBER OF COLUMNS with the COLUMNS HAVING SIMILAR DATA TYPES. The STRUCTURE is the same, only new rows are being added.

In joins, you can combine tables/result sets with any possible structure, including a cartesian join where there are NO shared/similar columns.

Answer (score -3):

I like to think of the general difference as being:

- JOINS join tables
- UNION (et all) combines queries.

Comment: This begs the question--join is mentioned in terms of "join" & union is mentioned in terms of unexplained "combines". Anyway what do you think you would be adding beyond other highly-voted 10-year-old answers that makes this "useful"? (Rhetorical.) See the voting arrow mouseover text.