# What is the difference between union and join?

Tags: sql, join, union

What is the difference between the SQL keywords `union` and `join`?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905379/what-is-the-difference-between-join-and-union

Answer (score 16):

The [`UNION`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more `SELECT` statements.

The [`JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) keyword is used in an SQL statement to query data from two or more tables, based on a relationship between certain columns in these tables.

The tutorials on these two topics (linked to above) on w3schools.com go into further detail.

Comment: Also, A union is from the branch of mathematics called set theory. 
 
This is a good image of a union
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Venn0111.svg

Answer (score 4):

Think of joins as horizontal and unions as vertical

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? As stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/905383/1170330 `union` combines results one after the other (horizontally), whereas `join` combines them side by side (vertically).

Comment: @user1170330 My answer matches the other answer. I think you have your directions confused.

Comment: UNION puts lines from queries after each other, while JOIN makes a cartesian product and subsets it -- completely different operations. It is just like the SO link @EvgenijReznik mentions about.

Answer (score 1):

Union is a combination of elements from multiple sets.

Join is a subset of the cross product of multiple sets

Answer (score 1):

If need combinate more then one queries use operator Union, this operator execute first query and the second query, and then return all result in one dataset [see more](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

```
select field from t1
union 
select field from t2
```

If need create query to select data from two or more table then use operator join [see more](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

```
select t1.field, t2.field
from t1.number inner join t2.key on t1.number=t2.key
```

Answer (score 0):

Union:

1. In `UNION` you need to take care That col length, datatype and no.of columns used in `SELECT` statement should be same in both tables
2. The result is displayed with first table column names as a combination of data from two tables by eliminating duplicates
3. To use `UNION` you should have at least two `SELECT` statements

Join:

1. In `JOIN`s there is no need to have rules mentioned in point 1.
2. The result is displayed with all columns mentioned in query depending on the type of `JOIN` used(Outer, Inner,Cartesian..)
3. One `SELECT` statement is enough

Hope this helps u..