# Combine SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between Join and Union?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905379/what-is-the-difference-between-join-and-union)

How do we combine separate queries into single sql statement? example:

```
SELECT packageid FROM tblhosting WHERE id='$id' AND userid='$userid'
SELECT id FROM tblcustomfields WHERE relid=tblhosting.packageid AND fieldname='foo'
SELECT value FROM tblcustomfieldsvalues WHERE fieldid=tblcustomfields.id AND relid='$id'
```

Now, I am aware of nested queryes, so I could write this like this:

but I was wondering if there is a better way to write this query?

**[Update2]**
here is a version without variables, hope its more clear this time

```
SELECT packageid FROM tblhosting WHERE id='$id' AND userid='$userid'
SELECT id FROM tblcustomfields WHERE relid=tblhosting.packageid AND fieldname='foo'
SELECT value FROM tblcustomfieldsvalues WHERE fieldid=tblcustomfields.id AND relid='$id'
```

here I only interested in `tblcustomfieldvalues.value`

Comment: It's hard to provide a "good" answer when names and variables are changed in small ways after originally posting the question.

Comment: @imm Fixed it now, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INNER or LEFT JOIN` for that depending on your need.

```
SELECT  c.value
  FROM  tblhosting a INNER JOIN tblcustomfields b
            ON b.relid = a.packageid
        INNER JOIN tblcustomfieldsvalues c
            ON c.fieldid = b.id
 WHERE  a.id = '$id'  AND   
        a.userid = '$userid' AND 
        b.fieldname = 'foo'
```

Comment: this query works fine except the fact, it returns multiple different records but if I run 3seperate queries, it returns me a single unique record.

Comment: i have updated the answer. I removed the two columns since you only need this column: `tblcustomfieldvalues.value` Right?

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
SELECT h.packageid, cf.id, cfv.value
FROM tblhosting h
INNER JOIN tblcustomfields cf ON (cf.relid = h.packageid)
INNER JOIN tblcustomfieldsvalues cfv ON (cfv.fieldid = cf.id)
WHERE h.id = '$serviceid'
  AND h.userid = '$userid'
  AND cf.fieldname = 'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rows from all three tables only where rows exist in all three tables, which is what I am assuming you want, the SQL looks like this:

```
select
    a.id,
    b.value,
    c.packageid
from
    tbcustomfields a,
    tblcustomfieldsvalues b,
    tblhosting c
where
    c.userid='$userid'
    and a.relid=b.relid
    and a.relid=c.packageid
    and a.fieldname='foo'
    and b.fieldid=c.id
```

Comment: Please use ANSI joins where possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  tblcustomfieldvalues.value
FROM tblhosting
  LEFT JOIN tblcustomfields
    ON tblcustomfields.relid = tblhosting.packageid
      AND tblcustomfields.fieldname = 'foo'
  LEFT JOIN tblcustomfieldsvalues
    ON tblcustomfieldsvalues.fieldid = tblcustomfields.id
      AND relid = '$id'
WHERE tblhosting.id = '$id'
    AND tblhosting.userid = '$userid'
```

TRY THIS