# Join operation on two tables retrieving dates

Tags: sql

My **first query**, retrieving `date` and `hours` worked from `work_details` of a given `employee number` in a given `date`.

```
SELECT date,
       SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `total_hours` ) ) ) AS total
FROM `work_details`
WHERE employee_id='28'
  and date between  '2012-02-01'
  and '2012-02-29'
GROUP BY DATE ORDER BY DATE
```

and the **Second query** retrieving `date` from table `holy_date`:

```
SELECT holy_date
from holiday
where holy_date between '2012-02-01' and '2012-02-29'
```

I need to combine results of the two queries in the  correct date order. 
I tried union operation,but dint get result.

How can I do it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  You can't use union unless you have the same number of columns in both queries.

Comment: how do you combine two result sets that have unequal number of fields?

Comment: Yes, i understood that when i tried with union!!! Im trying to combine working days from work_details table and holidays entries from holiday table, both are of date type in sql. Im required to get the total working hours of a given day, -> SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `total_hours` ) ) ) AS total implies this!!

Comment: yep! But there is no way, ? I'm using this combined result set for finding the leaves taken by an employee, days which is not coming as holidays and working days  can taken as leaves , no? and if the hours worked in a day is less than 4 hours , i need to count that day as half day leave , thats y i require hours too!

Comment: @JojoGeorge and since on holidays none bothers about working hours, u can neglect that field as nulls :)

Comment: @JojoGeorge Are you trying to get date, total, holy_date in one row? What are the fields in holyday table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Join and Union?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905379/what-is-the-difference-between-join-and-union)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve what you want.

This is not the documented way of doing it. But this should work.

```
SELECT   date, total
FROM 
         (
          SELECT   date, SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `total_hours` ) ) ) AS total 
          FROM     `work_details` 
          WHERE    employee_id='28' AND date BETWEEN  '2012-02-01' AND '2012-02-29' 
          GROUP BY date 

          UNION ALL

          (  
           SELECT holy_date AS date, NULL AS total 
           FROM   holiday 
           WHERE holy_date BETWEEN '2012-02-01' AND '2012-02-29'
          )
         ) AS t
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date
```

Comment: Exactly thats what i wanted :) Thanks Lot yaar :)

Comment: I have a doubt regarding this , when i use UNION ALL i get duplicate values . that is, if same date is in both queries,then answer shows both  dates as separate entries, but i need to have only distinct dates in my answer , what to do?

Comment: @JojoGeorge why not ask it straight? :)

Comment: straight means chat? im not used with this site,so kindly tell me how can i chat with u?

Comment: @JojoGeorge I dont think u have enough reputation to chat. By straight, I meant without an introduction, why dont you ask the question directly. Since you edited your comment, let me read it

Comment: see this example,                              2012-01-11 08:00:00                                      (result from table holiday,i NULL changed it to 08:00:00 as for default)
2012-01-11 07:53:17(answer from table workdetails),if same date ,how to give priority to latter answer? i mean answer from table workdetails

Comment: 2012-01-11 08:00:00                                          2012-01-11 07:53:17 , same date as two different dates i got when i used UNION ALL, i need only 2012-01-11 07:53:17

Comment: @JojoGeorge oh shit. Sorry I missed something trivial. Let me edit my answer. wait. and then see. But mind u there are many ways to achieve this. Is performance critical here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13115/discussion-between-jojo-george-and-nawfal)

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY date ORDER BY date ' at line 12   shows this error!