# Create a single query to display the names of all the tables with the following prefixes: V$_, ALL_, USER_

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sqlplus

this query produces a list of all the tables that begin with V$.

```
select TABLE_NAME
from DICTIONARY
where TABLE_NAME LIKE 'V$%';
```

how do I add the remaning prefixes to this query? I have tried parenthesis, using AND, ||, OR. I cannot find the answer to this in googling although I have gotten this far in searching, I believe the % I learned from a answer to a diff question.

If not for the single query requirement I would just make a script that runs the query three times once for each prefix which works great, I just cant figure out how to consolodate it into one query. thanks.

Comment: `or` should work fine. How did you write that query?

Comment: thanks to this post I think I solved it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364187/combining-2-sql-queries-and-getting-result-set-in-one.

Comment: select table_name from dictionary where table_name like 'V$_%' or  table_name like 'ALL_%' or table_name like 'USER_%';   can someone verify this is the best way to do this as it did produce the desired resulting list....

Comment: Good that it's solved. Can you post the answer? Maybe it will be helpful to future visitors.

Comment: For all the v$ views and filter the tables, you could follow my answer.

Comment: @GolezTrol, the query I posted above is the answer I submitted that produced the results I needed, I just wanted to make sure that it was the most efficient query to get a single response that selected tables with the three prefixes.

Comment: @Lalit Kumar B, The goal was to get an answer that included the three prefixes and excluded all the other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT table_name
FROM dictionary 
WHERE table_name LIKE 'V$\_%' ESCAPE '\'
  OR table_name LIKE 'ALL\_%' ESCAPE '\'
  OR table_name LIKE 'USER\_%' ESCAPE '\';
```

Comment: you should append `ESCAPE '\'` to every `LIKE` condition. Underscore is a wildcard for any character. Like '?' in Unix.

Comment: @ibre5041- can you give an example? I used underscore because all the tablenames began like the prefix example, are you saying its redundant because the % sign would take it anyways?

Answer (score 1):

How about `V$FIXED_TABLE`.

From the docs,

> This view displays all dynamic performance tables, views, and derived tables in the database. Some V$ tables (for example, V$ROLLNAME) refer to real tables and are therefore not listed.

You could filter the `TABLE` or `VIEW` using the `TYPE` column.

For a broader result, you could have a look at `V$FIXED_VIEW_DEFINITION`. From the docs,

> This view contains the definitions of all the fixed views (views beginning with V$). Use this table with caution. Oracle tries to keep the behavior of fixed views the same from release to release, but the definitions of the fixed views can change without notice. Use these definitions to optimize your queries by using indexed columns of the dynamic performance tables.

Comment: thank you for that, so much to learn. I appreciate your answer.