# how can i set the alias of column`s sum value based on another column in same table in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of `Accounts`, having columns:

`Acc_Id`, `Transaction_TypeId`, `Amount`

I want to get result as When `Transaction_TypeId = 1` then Sum of Amount as 'Total Advance Payments'.

Else when `Transaction_typeId = 2` then Sum of Amount as 'Total Reciepts'

Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS 'Sum' , Transaction_TypeId INTO #temp1  FROM AccountDetailTable WHERE  Account_MasterId = 1 GROUP BY Transaction_TypeId

SELECT Sum as 'Total Advance' from #temp1  WHERE #temp1.Transaction_TypeId = 1;
SELECT Sum as 'Total Cash Receipts' FROM #temp1  WHERE #temp1.Transaction_TypeId = 2;

DROP TABLE #temp1;
```

but this query returns me two different result sets. How can i get the values in same result sets?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364187/combining-2-sql-queries-and-getting-result-set-in-one

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN Transaction_TypeId = 1 THEN somecolumn END) as [Total Advance],
        SUM(CASE WHEN Transaction_TypeId = 2 THEN somecolumn END) as [Total Cash Receipts]
FROM #temp1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use CASE EXPRESSION like this:

```
SELECT
       sum(case when #temp1.Transaction_TypeId = 1 then amount else 0 end) as 'Total Advance',
       sum(case when #temp1.Transaction_TypeId = 2 then amount else 0 end) as 'Total Cash Receipts'
FROM #temp1
```