# How do I pivot values into columns with SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I made a table called `tbl` with this code:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
    (
      `Year` int, 
      `Album` varchar(255),
      `Artist` varchar(255),
      `Label` varchar(255),
      `Genre` varchar(255),
      `id` int
    )
;

INSERT INTO tbl
    (
      `Year`,
      `Album`,
      `Artist`,
      `Label`,
      `Genre`,
      `id`
    )
VALUES
    (1990, "Greatest Hits", "The Best", "Least Def", "hip hop", 123),
    (1990, "Greatest Hits", "The Best", "Roofless", "hip hop", 123),
    (1990, "4-Boyz", "3 Guyz", "Pacific", "pop-dance", 23),
    (1990, "4-Boyz", "3 Guyz", "Atlantic", "pop-dance", 23)
;
```

I want to run a query to show me the count of genres for each year, without double counting because of the `Label` column. I want this:

```
Year, hip hop, pop-dance
1990, 1, 1
```

What query must I run to get what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you can't use `pivot`, you can do this.

```
select year,
count(distinct case when `Genre` = 'hip hop' then 1 end) as hiphop,
count(distinct case when `Genre` = 'pop-dance' then 1 end) as popdance
from tbl
group by year
```

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/763ad/3 If they want to mess around with it anymore.

Comment: If I add more rows with more different Genres, is there a way to take those into account without having to add more `count(distinct case when `Genre` = 'new genre' then 1 end) as newgenre` statements?

Comment: No,unfortunately afaik. You will have to do this manually. If it were SQL Server or Oracle you would have had an option of doing a dynamic pivot.

Comment: @vkp How about MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer worked for me.

I add here a more complex case, with join, in case someone needs.

see also:

[Combining the results of two SQL queries as separate columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364187/combining-2-sql-queries-and-getting-result-set-in-one)

my example:

```sql
    select Info.*, Roots.*, ColeColeFit.*, f10.*, f20k.*
    from Info
    join (select * from Data where Frequency = 10) as f10
      on f10.Info_ID = Info.id
    join (select * from Data where Frequency = 20000) as f20k
      on f20k.Info_ID = Info.id
    join Roots
      on Info.File_Num = Roots."Plant number"
    join ColeColeFit
      on ColeColeFit.id = Info.id
```