# combine 2 sql's from different tables into one query

Tags: sql

I have for example as first query: (ararnr = article number)

```
Select ararnr,ararir,aoarom from ar left join ao ON AR.ARARNR=AO.AOARNR WHERE AR.ARARKD=1389
```

the second query uses the result from the first column from the first query to search in another table

```
Select votgan, sum(ststan) as totalStock from vo INNER JOIN st  on vo.voarnr=st.starnr where voarnr = ararnr
```

How could I combine both ?

Please note : Not all articlenumbers from the first query will be found in the second, but I need them in my result.

In the result I need the columns from both queries.

**EDIT**

for example :

first query returns article numbers and the description:

```
+---------+--------------+
|  ararnr |    aoarom    |
+---------+--------------+
| a123456 | description1 |
| b123456 | description2 |
| 0123456 | description3 |
+---------+--------------+
```

second query returns the totalstock for those articles:

```
+---------+--------------+
|  ararnr |  totalstock  |
+---------+--------------+
| a123456 |      12      |
| b123456 |              |
| 0123456 |       6      |
+---------+--------------+
```

Note the second one doesn't return a value since the articlenumber doesn't exist in this table.

In my result I would like to get the articlenumber with corresponding description and stock.

```
+---------+--------------+-----------+---------+
|  ararnr |    aoarom    | totalStock| vovoan  |
+---------+--------------+-----------+---------+
| a123456 | description1 |     12    |   2     |
| b123456 | description2 |           |   1     |
| 0123456 | description3 |      6    |         |
+---------+--------------+-----------+---------+
```

I'm using sql on **db2**

**SECOND EDIT**

The first query will select some article numbers (ararnr) from table **ar** and find the corresponding description (aoarom) in another table **ao**.

The second query finds the stock (vovoan and sum ststan) from two differend tables **vo** and **st** for the article numbers found in the first query.

The result should have the article number with corresponding description with corresponding stock from vo and st

Comment: Combine how? Show us sample result for the two select's, plus the combined result.

Answer (score 1):

I can't fully understand what you're asking, but another join may assist you.

example:

```
SELECT ar.ararnr, ar.ararir, ar.ararom, vo.votgan, SUM(vo.ststan) as totalStock
FROM ar LEFT JOIN ao ON [id=id] LEFT JOIN vo ON [id=id]
```

Because I can't tell what your tables structure are, or what you're really asking for, this is the best response I can give you.

This also may be what you're looking for:
[Combining 2 SQL queries and getting result set in one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16364187/combining-2-sql-queries-and-getting-result-set-in-one)

Answer (score 0):

You'd get a much more complete answer if you were to post the table structure and desired result, but..

You can use the first query as a resultset for your second query, and join to it. something like:

```
Select 
  votgan, 
  sum(ststan) as totalStock 
from vo 
inner join (Select 
              ararnr,
              ararir,
              ararom 
            from ar 
            left join ao .....) z on vo.voarnr = z.ararnr
```

EDIT:

```
Select 
  votgan, 
  sum(ststan) as totalStock,
  z.ararnr,
  z.aoarom
from vo 
inner join (Select 
              ararnr,
              ararir,
              ararom 
            from ar 
            left join ao .....) z on vo.voarnr = z.ararnr
```

Comment: Tried this. This only seems to return the items found in table vo. I also don't know how to get for example ararnr or aoarom. I tried to add it in the first select but that doesn't work ....

Comment: When I change SUM(ststan) to just ststan the code works, but of course I d"ont get the sum of ststan. I definitly need the sum of ststan. The error message I get when the SUM is in the code : SELECT WITH NO GROUP BY HAS COL NAME/FUNC OR COL NAME NOT IN GROUP BY. VOVOAN

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query.

```
SELECT ar.ararnr, ar.ararir, ar.ararom, vo.votgan, SUM(vo.ststan) as totalStock 
FROM ar 
LEFT JOIN ao ON ao.ararnr = ar.ararnr 
LEFT JOIN vo ON vo.voarnr = ao.ararnr
```

Comment: Tried this but getting an error :"ILLEGAL USE OF KEYWORD LEFT; TOKEN FOR USE SKIP WAIT WITH FETCH LIMIT OFFSET OPTIMIZE WAS EXPECTED"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server as database then this can be done with help of `OUTER APPLY`

```
SELECT ararnr,aoarom ,temp.totalStock 
FROM ar 
LEFT JOIN ao ON AR.ARARNR=AO.AOARNR 
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT sum(ststan) as totalStock 
    FROM vo 
    INNER JOIN st on vo.voarnr=st.starnr 
    where voarnr = ar.ararnr
)temp
WHERE AR.ARARKD=1389
```

Comment: I'm using sql on db2. It seems it doesn't support Outer Apply.