# Select SUM of columns in unrelated tables in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I have these tables which are not related at all:

```
Books                          Apps                           Cars                       

Id     Views                   Id     Views                   Id     Views
------------                   ------------                   ------------
1      3                       4      5                       11      10
2      4                       5      100                     13      3
3      3                       6      5                       15      7



I want:

total_books    total_apps    total_cars
10             110           20
```

Instead of 3 separate queries for the sum of views, I would like to have 1 query where I will get the sum of views in each table

```
SELECT SUM(books.views), SUM(apps.views), SUM(cars.views) FROM books,apps,cars;

giving me NULL NULL NULL
```

Comment: What does the query you've written there give you? (Ignoring the 'giving me...' part; what's that about?)

Comment: Why is this tagged with MongoDB?

Comment: @simonatrcl As I said, the query gives me NULL NULL NULL

Comment: @user20042973 I thought it was something general not relating to a specific DBS

Comment: @Venda97 OK. (I didn't understand that that was the result, since it's formatted the same as the query I assumed it was part of the query and so asked about it. D'oh!) If the tables are empty then I would expect that result. Are you sure that there is data in the tables?

Comment: @simonatrcl Of course I do. I brought example that with having those data in tables, I get NULLs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would still need multiple selects since the tables are not related.

Try this (credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16364510/12080599)):

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT SUM(Views) as total_books from Books) as Books, (SELECT Sum(Views) as total_apps from Apps) as Apps, (SELECT Sum(Views) as total_cars from Cars) as Cars`

[screenshot of my test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq7dN.png)

There are probably better/more performant ways to accomplish this, but at least it is a start.

### Edit

#### Running your example

If I run the same command you did, the results are multiplied by 9 instead (see it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbx00.png)).

#### Most likely situation - empty table

I just realized your results are coming back as null. So as pointed out by others, your table must be empty. In my examples, I created the Views field as `NOT NULL` so I would never run into what you did.

[see example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POlSC.png)

### Edit 2

It would be useful to provide additional information about where you are running your queries. Could you be accidentally running the queries against a different version of the tables (maybe a different context window in your software)?

Comment: Thank you, I realized that the reason for my query getting NULLs was not their emptiness but the qty of tables. I have got 8 of them each having column views with data inside them. When I reduce it to 3, I also get multiplied by 8 (as your example).

Comment: Still, I have to admit that your answer is meeting my requirements and thanks for that. I will try to find some optimal solutions though.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT SUM(Views) from Books) as Books,
    (SELECT Sum(Views) from Apps)  as Apps,
    (SELECT Sum(Views) from Cars)  as Cars ;
```

(No need for 'derived' tables.)

Some databases (other than MySQL) may need `FROM DUAL` on the end.

Comment: Is there any other more efficient and shorter solution?

Comment: I pulled out a few unnecessary keystrokes; now I think this is the best by any metric.