# MySQL Query; Combine two tables

Tags: mysql, select-query

I have two tables: `Invoice`

```
 id number   date      client end client city   vracht
  1   4271   2014-5-28 ALLIN  STIHO      ZWOLLE 0
```

and `Materials`.

```
 id number material thickness length width amount price
  1 14271  Ocoume          10   2500  1220    150   2,3
  2 14271  Ocoume          15   2500  1220     60   2,3
  3 14271  Ocoume          18   2500  1220    125   2,3
  4 14271  Ocoume          22   2500  1220     44   2,3
  5 14271  Ocoume          40   2150  1000     72   2,3
  6 14271  Ocoume          18   3100  1530     25   2,3
```

In the `Invoice` table are the invoices. In the `Materials` table are the materials that belong to the invoices.

What I want is to combine those, which have the same invoice number (number column in the table), with a select-query, like this:

```
number date      client end client city   vracht material thickness length width amount price
 14271 2014-5-28 ALLIN  STIHO      ZWOLLE      0 Ocoume          10   2500  1220    150   2,3
 14271 2014-5-28 ALLIN  STIHO      ZWOLLE      0 Ocoume          15   2500  1220     60   2,3
 14271 2014-5-28 ALLIN  STIHO      ZWOLLE      0 Ocoume          18   2500  1220    125   2,3
 14271 2014-5-28 ALLIN  STIHO      ZWOLLE      0 Ocoume          22   2500  1220     44   2,3
 14271 2014-5-28 ALLIN  STIHO      ZWOLLE      0 Ocoume          40   2150  1000     72   2,3
 14271 2014-5-28 ALLIN  STIHO      ZWOLLE      0 Ocoume          18   3100  1530     25   2,3
```

How would this query look?

Comment: @shree.pat18 How do I use JOIN?

Comment: check for inner join

Comment: how are these two tables linked? which columns?

Comment: @MZeinstra You could always start with the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: is there a foreign key relation?

Comment: Because you dont have a forign key relation use a UNION?

Comment: @Aditya No there isn't a a key relation. @Harry nothing is linked, except the `number` column, but those do not have a relation.

Comment: best practice would be to link the tables, so material id column can sit in invoices. and then you can perform a join.

Comment: @MZeinstra you should learn the joins for that..well I have written the query that will perform your required task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select 
    `f`.`number`,
    `f`.`client`, 
    `f`.`eind_client`, 
    `f`.`city`, 
    `f`.`vracht`,
        `m`.`material`, 
        `m`.`thickness`, 
        `m`.`length`, 
        `m`.`width`, 
        `m`.`amount`, 
        `m`.`price`
from 
     `invoice` as `f` 
right outer join 
     `materials` as `m`
on 
    `f`.`number`=`m`.`number`
```

Comment: This works good, but not perfect.. Every record of `materials` shows up 6 times.. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe try instead join use left(or right) outer join.

Comment: Okay, right join works.. I've also added group by, so if you accept my edit, I can accept your answer :)

Comment: Sorry, this edit was wrong.. I don't need Group by.. Please accept my edit :)

Answer (score 3):

```
 select * from  invoice, materials where invoice.number=materials.number
```

Instead of *, it is recommended to write down the required columns..

Comment: You should use the JOIN keyword along with the type of join rather than this style.

Comment: @shree.pat18 this is basically inner join,  if you want to write the word inner join, it will be like .. select * from  invoice inner join materials on invoice.number=materials.number

Comment: There was a single character typo but the site requires a minimum of 6 character edits. Shish!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an JOIN to retrieve the columns from both tables.

example:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    Invoice AS i,
    Materials AS m,
WHERE
    m.number = i.number
    AND
    m.number = 14271
```

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo: Have read the question? From the table 3, I don't see any other number than 14271.

Comment: This is a silly topic to argue about. The OP didn't ask for all the records. And this is simple enough query to understand and modify.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a join.

```
  SELECT * FROM Material as M LEFT JOIN Invoice as I ON I.number=M.Number
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, If you have a foreign key relation you could use  `JOIN.` That should give you the desired outcome.

You could use:

```
Select "columns you need " or "* "from invoice, materials 
WHERE invoice.number = material.number
```

Comment: That is not how UNION works. UNION will combine result sets i.e. Set 1 followed by Set 2. It will not append columns from Set 2 to the columns of Set 1, which is what OP wants.

Comment: No. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905379/what-is-the-difference-between-join-and-union