# using the ids returned from insert into, for record insertion with foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table

`monster(id serial, name varchar, primary key(id))`

and i have another table

`ranged_monster(id_monster integer, distance integer, foreign key(id_monster) references monster)`

I want to insert two ranged monsters: one is called **'archer goblin'** with a range attack distance of **10**, and the another is called **'dragon'** with a range attack distance of **50**. How can i do this in one instruction?

so far, i have tried this:

**the worst way**

```
insert into monster(name) values ('archer goblin'), ('dragon');

insert into ranged_monster(distance) values (10) where name='archer goblin';

insert into ranged_monster(distance) values (50) where name='dragon';
```

it is bad because the name column allows repetitions, and the retrieved records might be more than one... also having to write the name of the monster twice does not seems like a good habit.

**insert into ... returning**

if the table `ranged_monster` only had the column (foreign key) of the `id_monster`, then i could use this solution:

```
with the_ids as (
    insert into monster(name) 
    values ('archer goblin'), ('dragon') 
    returning id
) 
insert into ranged_monster(id_monster) 
    select * from the_ids;
```

however it does not work, because ranged_monster also has the column `distance`. Doing so, will insert the ids of the monsters without `distance`.

**possible solutions**

create a temporal table with the distances, and then combine this temporal table sequentially with the `insert into ... returning`'s `the_ids`, and then insert this combined records into the `ranged_monster` table.

How can i combine two tables as asked in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31171253/sql-combine-two-tables ? (it was marked as duplicated, linking to this [What is the difference between JOIN and UNION?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905379/what-is-the-difference-between-join-and-union) , but that question **is not related** to that another question.)

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to return each inserted ID?

Comment: i want to know the inserted id's, because i need to insert a record into `ranged_monster`'s table with this ids.

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944297/postgresql-function-for-last-inserted-id It might help you along

Comment: yeah, it is a very useful question... thanks :D i extracted the second possible solution from there... i can retrieve the inserted ids, but i can't combine them with the additional data i need to insert :(

Comment: can i assume that your inserts are getting data from an external application? You could use a transaction with the `currval()` function to insert each "item" seperatly, and a loop in your application to handle multiple inserts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with s(name, distance) as (
    values ('archer goblin', 10), ('dragon', 50)
), the_ids as (
    insert into monster(name) 
    select name
    from s
    returning id, name
)
insert into ranged_monster (id_monster, distance)
select id, distance
from
    s
    inner join
    the_ids using (name)
```

Comment: you are a genius! it works!! thanks!! I just wanted to point that inner joining the_ids with s using the name is absolutely necessary, because s has not the ids.

also, this inner join will only search for names inside the s variable, preventing from retrieving duplicated ids from the monster table.

Comment: @Bengalaa BTW why isn't `name` the primary key of the `monster` table? Are there other columns in that table?