# Is Union works on any Implicit joins

Tags: sql

In `UNION` their will be no duplicate values so it will search other table entirely before considering a row.

dose it make `UNION` as a kind of join?

Comment: Short answer, no. `JOIN` and `UNION` are different operations.

Comment: UNION operator is just for combining two or more SELECT statements. 

While, JOIN is for select rows from each tables either Inner, Outer, Left or right method. you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905379/what-is-the-difference-between-join-and-union

Comment: Why the SQL Server and Oracle tags? Don't tag products not involved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I asked question too soon. i.e without trying everything.

I misunderstood the working of `UNION` so I created a plan for union and found that  before `UNION`  `UNION ALL` will execute and from the result set we are extracting unique set of data.

explain plan for

```
select * from table_a
union
select * from table_b
```

plan output came like this

[image]

Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 2):

> dose it make UNION as a kind of join?

**NO**

UNION is used to combine the result of two queries.  Whereas JOIN is used to get the data using a logical relationship between the tables.

[UNION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)

> Combines the results of two or more queries into a single result set
>   that includes all the rows that belong to all queries in the union.
>   **The UNION operation is different from using joins that combine columns
>   from two tables.**

[JOIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517.aspx)

> By using joins, you can retrieve data from two or more tables based on
>   logical relationships between the tables. Joins indicate how Microsoft
>   SQL Server should use data from one table to select the rows in
>   another table.

Comment: @NarasimhaMaiya:- You are comparing oranges with apple. Also there is no linking, so which background process you are talking about?

Comment: Before i wrote a answer at the top. I thought like union do not contains any duplicate data set from two table. so i thought it will compare 2 data and then it will add it to the result set. For those kind of comparison their is a implicit join called `anti-join`. But i proved wrong.

Comment: Go through my answer.

Comment: @NarasimhaMaiya:- If you are clear about it then heads up! I know what it does. Thanks

Comment: Thank you too for finding time for answering such a silly question.

Answer (score 1):

To make VERY simple:
 - with JOIN you put 2 datasets - generally with different columns, "side by side",
 - with UNION you put 2 datasets - with identical columns - one above the other

Comment: For that comparison is necessary and as per my Knowledge  without join comparing is not possible. So oracle Engine should use join.