# Joining 2 tables to query for missing entry

Tags: php, mysql, join

I currently have two tables, "tc_services" and "tc_users" which both have a "USER_ID" field and "BILLING_ID" field. I need to query these together, finding any results where...

A) "tc_services" does not have a "BILLING_ID"

B) "tc_users" does not contain a "USER_ID" that matches that of the coorelating "tc_services"

I am trying to put together a JOIN query statement such as the following but not able to figure it out so far. Any help would be appreciated!

```
SELECT *
FROM tc_services AS services
JOIN tc_users AS users
WHERE services.USER_ID NOT IN users.USER_ID AND services.BILLING_ID = '';
```

[image: Users]

[image: Services]

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking. Could you post the relevant table schemas, example data, and expected output?

Comment: Are you looking for services where there is no entry in users? Or an entry in users, but with no USER_ID. What is the foreign key between services and users? I do agree that table schema would be very helpful to see how to construct this query.

Comment: I added pictures of the schema to original post. Basically we are looking for entries in "tc_services" which A) Do not have a "BILLING_ID" value set and B) have a "USER_ID" value set that does not exist in the "tc_users" table.

Comment: Pseudo example would be "SELECT * FROM tc_services WHERE tc_services.billing_id = '' AND tc_services.user_id NOT EXISTS tc_users"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT SERVICE_ID, COUNT(users.USER_ID)
FROM tc_services AS services
LEFT JOIN tc_users AS users ON services.USER_ID = users.USER_ID
WHERE services.BILLING_ID = ''
GROUP BY services.SERVICE_ID HAVING COUNT(users.USER_ID) = 0
```

Comment: the mysql syntax might be off a little, im usually working with sql server and this is not tested.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I am getting an SQL error which appears to be between the "*)" and "users.USER_ID =" but trying to figure out what it is now.

Comment: Thanks! No more errors but no results where there should be quite a few. I think the issue is "ON users.USER_ID = services.USER_ID". We're trying to find where the "tc_services.USER_ID" has doesn't exist in "tc_users.USER_ID"

Comment: alright, found the issue, should only count the users.user_id, not *

Comment: the way left join works is you'll get null values where the join couldnt be made. then you can use that information to further filter your query.

Comment: I will just go ahead and accept this one as I believe it is correct, I am just not getting the proper results at the moment and trying to figure out why. I made a few edits to your response such as changing "services" to "tc_services" and "IS NULL" to "=' '" just to bring it more in line with what we are actually looking for. Hopefully can find the issue shortly. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Second Edit after seeing your comment:

Just do

```
SELECT 
*
FROM tc_services 
WHERE tc_services.billing_id IS NULL AND
tc_services.user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM tc_users)
```

No joins needed

Edit:
After rereading your question, you might want an 'LEFT JOIN'

see this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/66zgg.png

So your query(s) would look something like

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM tc_users u
LEFT JOIN tc_services s ON a.user_id = s.user_id
WHERE s.billing_id IS NULL
```

which would give you the list of users that don't have a billing ID.

and then similar for the second question.

Original Answer:
Sounds like you might want to use a 'Union' rather than a 'Join'

Check out this related answer: [What is the difference between JOIN and UNION?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905379/what-is-the-difference-between-join-and-union)