# Preparing and executing two queries

Tags: php, pdo

If i have 2 queries like this

```
$query1 = "SELECT title, content, image FROM table1 WHERE id = :id";
$query2 = "SELECT title, content FROM table2 WHERE id = :id";
```

Can i prepare two of them at once like something like this

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query1, $query2);
$stmt->execute([':id' => $id]);
```

Comment: What error you are getting, when you run it

Comment: Google: "SQL Join" - thats what you're looking for ;)

Comment: You need to prepare the qeuries one by one... there isn't a multi prepare function..

Comment: @AjeetKumar `prepare() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given`

Comment: give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905379/what-is-the-difference-between-join-and-union) a read as well. I think union is what you need.

Comment: Add id 2 times in array ``$stmt->execute([':id' => $id,':id' => $id]);``

Comment: You can not put 2 queries in prepare(), but you can use join to get values from multiple table

Comment: @AjeetKumar Didn't work.

Comment: @CaliburVictorious because both are same key make it different keys and the check, it will work.
But its not correct way because both are select Query means 2 views will create

Comment: @AjeetKumar I guess the problem in the prepare`($query1, $query2);` before  the `execute()` problem and the `execute()` problem is `Call to a member function execute() on boolean`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [MySQL UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html).

Comment: The columns numbers isn't matched.

Comment: It is not problem. In second query you can do like this:

SELECT '' AS image

Comment: Didn't catch it correctly, so in the 2nd query i'll make it like this?
`$query = "SELECT title, content, image FROM table1 WHERE id = :id
UNION ALL SELECT title, content, image AS image FROM table2 WHERE id = :id
";`  or something like that? If possible put an example using my example

Comment: You can use it like that: `SELECT title, content, image FROM table1 WHERE id = :id 
UNION ALL 
SELECT title, content, '' AS image FROM table2 WHERE id = :id`