# Full Join operation and groupy by operation on two tabels

Tags: sql

Table1

```
MONTH   ACCT_NUM   PRODUCT   REVENUE
Jan     9994523    VEG        50.00 
Jan     9994523    HOT DOG    40.00 
Jan     9993644    HOT DOG    35.00 
Jan     9993644    FRIES      2.00 
Jan     9996984    VEG        60.00 
Jan     9996427               15.00
```

Table2

```
MONTH   ACCT_NUM   PRODUCT   REVENUE
Feb     9994523    VEG        50.00 
Feb     9994523    HOT DOG    40.00 
Feb     9993644    HOT DOG    35.00 
Feb     9993644    FRIES      2.00 
Feb     9996984    VEG        60.00 
Feb     9996427               15.00
```

Expected Output

```
ACCT_NUM    REVENUE_TOTAL
9993644     74.00 
9994523     180.00 
9996427     30.00 
9996984     120.00
```

I am trying to perform a full join on both the tables and performing a group by operation on top it. Is there anything wrong in my approach or is there a better approach the below queries

```
Q1 = SELECT T1.*
FROM Table1 T1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.ACCT_NUM = T2.ACCT_NUM

select distinct ACCT_NUM, sum(REVENUE) as REVENUE_TOTAL from Q1 group by ACCT_NUM
```

Comment: Does your query produces the expected outcome? If yes, does it produce the results within a reasonable timeframes? Btw mysql does not support full outer joins, so I removed that tag. Pls only use the relevant product tags, not just any random ones!

Comment: @Shadow I don't have an environment to check it. If I had I don't need to post the question here in the first place.

Comment: Then next time pls disclose such information in the question and specify a single target product environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Union All`.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f8e69/8

```
Select 
  ACCT_NUM, sum(REVENUE) REVENUE_TOTAL
From
  (
    Select ACCT_NUM, REVENUE from Table1
    Union All
    Select ACCT_NUM, REVENUE from Table2
  ) A
Group By A.ACCT_NUM
```

More readings for you :) Reference: [What is the difference between JOIN and UNION?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905379/what-is-the-difference-between-join-and-union)

> UNION puts lines from queries after each other, while JOIN makes a
>   cartesian product and subsets it...