# SQL EXCEPT across several columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to compare two almost identical select queries; both queries output the same columns, from the same table. Only the conditions are different on a single attribute (`where foo = 'BAR'` vs. `where foo <> 'BAR'`). The results are huge and might have only a few subtle differences. My current approach is to execute both queries and then put the results into Excel and use formulas to compare the two. Tedious and poor - there must be a better way.

How can I build a query that performs each select separately and then **shows me only those lines that don't exist on both sides?**

Here is a simplified version of my queries:

```
-- first query
select a.foo, a.bar, a.moo from abc.mytable a where a.somedetail = 'BAR'
group by a.foo, a.bar, a.moo
order by a.foo, a.bar, a.moo;

-- second query
select a.foo, a.bar, a.moo from abc.mytable a where a.somedetail <> 'BAR'
group by a.foo, a.bar, a.moo
order by a.foo, a.bar, a.moo;
```

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30503042/20571), it looks like I need either the EXCEPT operator (but in both directions, is that possible?), or either a UNION or a FULL OUTER JOIN but for those I don't really know how to set the WHERE clauses to match all the columns in the two sets yes having differences in the `somedetail` column.

This only needs to be executed once per database, but performance is very much a consideration because the data covers *many millions* of rows.

Comment: `EXCEPT` is called `MINUS` in Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `group by`, so you can write this as:

```
select a.foo, a.bar, a.moo
from abc.mytable a
where a.somedetail = 'BAR'
except
select a.foo, a.bar, a.moo
from abc.mytable a
where a.somedetail <> 'BAR';
```

Given that you are scanning all the data, you might find that `group by` works better:

```
select a.foo, a.bar, a.moo
from abc.mytable a
group by a.foo, a.bar, a.moo
having sum(case when a.somedetail = 'BAR' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when a.somedetail <> 'BAR' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

If you have an index on `(foo, bar, moo)`, Oracle should be smart about using it on this query.

Comment: Thank you Gordon! This looks very workable and I will test it in my actual (complex) case.