# Union v/s Inner join on 3 conditions in SQL

Tags: sql, inner-join, union

Will the following 2 SQL statements give same result?

SQL1-

```
A inner join B on (condition1)
union
A inner join B on (condition2)
union
A inner join B on (condition3)
```

SQL2-

```
A inner join B on (condition1) OR (condition2) OR (condition3)
```

Comment: Yes, they will.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between JOIN and UNION?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905379/what-is-the-difference-between-join-and-union)

Comment: @Bishan: How is that supposed to answer this question? Have you read the other question and its answers? Have you understood what wait's pseudo code queries are supposed to do?

Comment: Try this example.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=56106d853e41be23903904e349c9ffee

Comment: Good question to get people to think (me too).  The presence of rows/results with guaranteed unique detail vs cases where the result is not guaranteed to be unique, makes the difference.  It's tough to answer a general question with `yes` when there are specific cases (lots of them, although we only need one) where the answer is `no`.

Comment: @wait: See Serg's answer. I was a little quick saying yes. The real answer is obviously: "yes, if the selected rows are distinct".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least it depends on A or B originally having doubles. For example

```
with A(c) as (
 select 1 union all
 select 1 union all
 select 2 
 ),
B(c)  as (
 select 1 union all
 select 2 union all
 select 3 
 )
select *
from A join B on A.c=B.c
union
select *
from A join B on A.c>B.c
```

returns 3 rows (distinct).

```
with A(c) as (
 select 1 union all
 select 1 union all
 select 2 
 ),
B(c)  as (
 select 1 union all
 select 2 union all
 select 3 
 )
select *
from A join B on A.c=B.c or A.c>B.c
```

returns 4 rows due to A having doubles.

Comment: That is correct.  In the general case, the results can be different, so the answer really is `no`.  It's just that there are lots of specific cases where they are the same, and that's what most people tend to consider.

Comment: A great aswer. This is a case I didn't consider.