# How can I add a whole column of data as a row?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am dealing with a library database today.  The structure is kind of odd, and I am having trouble pulling the data how I want it to appear.

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    lc.catalogID, hb_g.intro AS 'Genre/Subject', gk.kidsAge AS 'Ages', 
    pb_g.intro AS 'Genre/Subject', pb.ageRange AS 'Ages'
FROM 
    library.libraryCatalog lc
INNER JOIN 
    library.hardbacks hb ON lc.catalogID = hb.catalogId
INNER JOIN 
    library.paperbacks pb ON lc.catalogID = pb.catalogId
LEFT JOIN 
    library.genres hb_g ON hb.genreId = hb_g.genreId 
LEFT JOIN 
    library.genres pb_g ON pb.genreId = pb_g.genreId
LEFT JOIN 
    library.bookSeries bs ON hb.id = bs.logId
LEFT JOIN 
    library.genreKids gk ON bs.kidsId = gk.kidsId
WHERE 
    lc.libraryID = 87
```

It produces results shown below. The issue I have is that I need the `Fairy Tales` and `12+` result to appear in the same columns as the other genres.

```
catalogID   Genre/Subject   Age up to   Genre/Subject   Ages
--------------------------------------------------------------
2021        Mystery         8+          Fairy Tales     12+
2021        Sci-Fi/Fantasy  12+         Fairy Tales     12+
2021        Fiction         10+         Fairy Tales     12+
2021        Non-Fiction     12+         Fairy Tales     12+
2021        Biography       16+         Fairy Tales     12+
2021        Historical      10+         Fairy Tales     12+
```

I am hoping for something like this:

```
catalogID   Genre/Subject   Age up to   
------------------------------------------
2021        Mystery         8+          
2021        Sci-Fi/Fantasy  12+         
2021        Fiction         10+         
2021        Non-Fiction     12+         
2021        Biography       16+         
2021        Historical      12+         
2021        Fairy Tales     12+  <---- moved here
```

I tried using `ISNULL` and `COALESCE` but neither of those worked.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: It really looks like fixing the design would be better here. Hardbacks and Softbacks shouldn't be different tables, they should be a single table, and then a column needs to denote if the book is a hardback or softback.

Comment: You should be able to use a UNION ALL between hardbacks and paperbacks and then it will all fall to place. If you also add a type column to the UNION, you can see if the book is hard or paperback as well

Comment: @ThomA Unfortunately I don't have access to do that.  The DB Team knows it's not an ideal design but do not have the resources to change it at this time.

Comment: @siggemannen unfortunately, there is no `TYPE` column in the table.

Comment: I know, that's why you create it yourself... `select 'hardback' as type, * from hardbacks union all select 'paperback', * from paperback`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to union two separate resultsets, then join back on `catalogID`.

```sql
SELECT 
    lc.catalogID,
    b.intro AS GenreOrSubject,
    b.Ages
FROM 
    library.libraryCatalog lc
JOIN (
    SELECT
        hb.catalogId,
        hb.genreId,
        gk.kidsAge AS Ages
    FROM
        library.hardbacks hb
    JOIN 
        library.bookSeries bs ON hb.id = bs.logId
    JOIN 
        library.genreKids gk ON bs.kidsId = gk.kidsId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        pb.catalogID,
        pb.genreId,
        pb.ageRange
    FROM
        library.paperbacks pb
) b
    ON lc.catalogID = b.catalogId
JOIN 
    library.genres b_g ON b.genreId = b_g.genreId 
WHERE
    lc.libraryID = 87;
```

Comment: So is `b` the main table ?  I am a little confused by how it's structured... thank you!

Comment: `b` is a union of both `hardbacks` and `paperbacks`, you then rejoin that back to ``libraryCatalog`

Comment: Why do you need the UNION ALL inside a JOIN?  That part I am having trouble understand...thank u

Comment: Because you need to union the two halves together (ie put them serially one after the other in rows, rather than joining laterally), then the final result can be joined back. Read up what Union vs Join is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905379/what-is-the-difference-between-join-and-union

Comment: `intro` comes from `b_g`, I believe.