# Merge and Update Two Lists in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, generic-list

I have two `List<T>` objects:

For example:

**List 1:**
ID, Value where Id is populated and value is blank and it contains say IDs from 1 to 10.
1,""
2,""
...
10,""

**List 2:**
ID, Value and other attributes all filled with values but this list is a subset of List 1 in terms of IDs. (e.g only 3 items)
2,67
4,90
5,98

What I want is a merged list 1, but with updated values. Does anyone have any good extension method which will do this or any elegent code to perform this operation. The final list should be:

ID, Value
1,""
2,67 //value from list 2
3,""
4,90
5,98
6,""
...
10,""

Comment: Is your *Value* a string or an int? You seems to show strings in List 1 whereas ints in List 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably use a dictionary rather than a list:

```
    // sample data
    var original = new Dictionary<int, int?>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        original.Add(i, null);
    }
    var updated = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    updated.Add(2, 67);
    updated.Add(4, 90);
    updated.Add(5, 98);
    updated.Add(11, 20); // add

    // merge
    foreach (var pair in updated)
    {
        original[pair.Key] = pair.Value;
    }

    // show results
    foreach (var pair in original.OrderBy(x => x.Key))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + ": " + pair.Value);
    }
```

If you are talking about **properties** of an object, it will be trickier, but still doable.

Answer (score 9):

use linq: list1=list2.Union(list1);

Comment: I tried your code with two lists of type `list<Student>` the class student looks like this `Student student = new Student(){Id=1, Name="foo"}` Using this syntax `list1 = list2.ToList().Union(list1.ToList()).ToList();` but it did not merge the two lists; it just glued them together like a [UNION -see example 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all). Are you sure it `merges the list with updated values`?

Comment: I found this question on how to [remove duplicates while merging lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980485/remove-duplicates-while-merging-lists-using-union-in-linq) and it confirms that your code works only if the class overrrides `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()`

Answer (score 3):

This is O(m*n) but should do the job for arbitrary lists

```
        foreach (var record in List1)
        {
            var other = List2.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == record.Key);
            if(other != null) record.Value = other.Value;
        }
```

If the lists are guaranteed ordered, then it could be brought down to O(n) at the cost of more code.  The algortihm would be

```
Current items start as head of each list
While items remain in both lists
  If the current item of list1 has lower key than list2  advance to next in list1
  else if the current item of list2 has lower key than list1  advance to next in list2
  else copy value from current list2 item into list1 item and advance both lists.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have *both lists sorted by ID*, you can use a variation of the classical merge algorithm:

```
int pos = 0;
foreach (var e in list2) {
  pos = list1.FindIndex(pos, x => x.Id==e.Id);
  list1[pos].Value = e.Value;
}
```

Note that this also requires `list2` to be a strict subset of `list1` in terms of ID (i.e. `list1` really contains *all* ids of `list2`)

Of course you can also wrap this in an extension method

```
public static void UpdateWith<T>(this List<T> list1, List<T> list2) 
where T:SomeIdValueSupertype {
  int pos = 0;
  foreach (var e in list2) {
    pos = list1.FindIndex(pos, x => x.Id==e.Id);
    list1[pos].Value = e.Value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
String searchBy = cmbSearchBy.Text.ToString();
String searchFor = txtSearchFor.Text.Trim();

var List3 = (from row in JobTitleDB.jobList
                         where (row.JID.ToString()+row.JobTitleName.ToString().ToLower()).Contains(searchFor.ToLower())
                         select row).ToList();
if (searchBy == "All")
            {
                dgJobTitles.DataSource = null;
                //dgJobTitles.DataSource = List1;
                //dgJobTitles.DataSource = List2;
                //dgJobTitles.DataSource = List1.Concat(List2);
                //dgJobTitles.DataSource = List1.Union(List2);
                dgJobTitles.DataSource = List3;
                //dgJobTitles.DataSource=List1.AddRange(List2);
            }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation here. Remove unnecessary commented code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<int, string> List1 = new Dictionary<int, string>();
List1.Add(1,"");
List1.Add(2,"");
List1.Add(3,"");
List1.Add(4,"");
List1.Add(5,"");
List1.Add(6,"");

Dictionary<int, string> List2 = new Dictionary<int, string>();
List2.Add(2, "two");
List2.Add(4, "four");
List2.Add(6, "six");

var Result = List1.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(x.Key, List2.ContainsKey(x.Key) ? List2[x.Key] : x.Value)).ToList();
```