# Remove duplicates while merging lists using Union in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to merge two lists using `list.Union` in `LinqPad` but I can't get it to work and wanted to check my understanding is correct.

Given this simple class:

```
public class Test 
{
   public int Id { get; set;}
   public int field1 { get; set; }

   public bool Equals(Test other)
   {        
      return this.Id.Equals(other.Id);
   }
}
```

And two lists populated like this:

```
List<Test> list = new List<Test>();
list.Add( new Test { Id = 1, field1 = 1});
list.Add( new Test { Id = 1, field1 = 2});
list.Add( new Test { Id = 2, field1 = 3});
list.Add( new Test { Id = 2, field1 = 4});

List<Test> list2 = new List<Test>();
list2.Add( new Test { Id = 1, field1 = 1});
list2.Add( new Test { Id = 1, field1 = 2});
list2.Add( new Test { Id = 2, field1 = 3});
list2.Add( new Test { Id = 2, field1 = 4});
```

I then try: `var mergedList = list.Union(list2).ToList();` and output the data using a simple `foreach` loop and get this output:

```
ID: 1 -------- 1
ID: 1 -------- 2
ID: 2 -------- 3
ID: 2 -------- 4
ID: 1 -------- 1
ID: 1 -------- 2
ID: 2 -------- 3
ID: 2 -------- 4
```

I was under the impression that `Union` should remove the duplicates to return:

```
ID: 1 -------- 1
ID: 1 -------- 2
ID: 2 -------- 3
ID: 2 -------- 4
```

Am I doing something wrong or have I misunderstood?

Also, should it work without explicitly overriding the `Equals` method in the `Test` class?

Thanks

Comment: You should read [this documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your case you simply define some method, that LINQ knows nothing about. It's like creating method `bool HeyEquateMeWith(Test other)` and expect, that LINQ will call it when doing set operations.

You need to define your class as following (**override** `Object`'s `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods):

```
public class Test 
{
   public int Id { get; set;}
   public int field1 { get; set; }  

   public override bool Equals(object other) //note parameter is of type object
   {        
        Test t = other as Test;
        return (t != null) ? Id.Equals(t.Id) : false;
   }

   public override int GetHashCode()
   {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
   }
}
```

Now `Union` will call your overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods. Also you should [ALWAYS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden) override `GetHashCode` when you override `Equals` method.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, I thought I could leave the GetHashCOde for an example but it is required.  How does the default comparer work for Union or do I always need to override Equals and GethashCode?

Comment: @davy default comparer will look at object identity (same functionality as `==` operator). If you change  your `Test` class to `struct`, the default equality will have value semantics (compare contents of two structs including `Id` and `field1`)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like that if not happy with default comparer (which is, in turn, utilizes GetHashCode method as @IlyaIvanov had mentioned):

```
// get all items that "other than in first list", so Where() and Any() are our filtering expressions
var delta = list2.Where(x2 => !list.Any(x1 => (x1.Id == x2.Id) && (x1.field1 == x2.field1)));

// now let merge two enumerables that have nothing "equal" between them
var merged = list.Union(delta).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class implementing

```
IEqualityComparer<Test>
```

Is this class define Equals and GetHashCode
After it you can pass this comparer to you Union method
Just like that:

```
public class MyComparer:IEqualityComparer<Test>{
//Equals and GetHashCode
}

var mergedList = list.Union(list2, new MyComparer()).ToList();
```

Comment: This will work for LINQ to Objects but is not supported for LINQ to Entities. I found this out the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to leave this here for anyone that still couldn't get it. I found this article super helpful about the compare class that inherits from IEqualityComparer 
 http://alicebobandmallory.com/articles/2012/10/18/merge-collections-without-duplicates-in-c