# SQL to get list of dates as well as days before and after without duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to display a list of dates, which I have in a table

```
SELECT mydate AS MyDate, 1 AS DateType
FROM myTable
WHERE myTable.fkId = @MyFkId;
```

> Jan 1, 2010 -  1
>   Jan 2, 2010 -  1
>   Jan 10, 2010 -  1

No problem. However, I now need to display the date before and the date after as well with a different DateType.

> Dec 31, 2009 -  2
>   Jan 1, 2010 -  1
>   Jan 2, 2010 -  1
>   Jan 3, 2010 -  2
>   Jan 9, 2010 -  2
>   Jan 10, 2010 -  1
>   Jan 11, 2010 -  2

I thought I could use a union

```
SELECT MyDate, DateType
FROM (
    SELECT mydate - 1 AS MyDate, 2 AS DateType
    FROM myTable
    WHERE myTable.fkId = @MyFkId;

    UNION

    SELECT mydate + 1 AS MyDate, 2 AS DateType
    FROM myTable
    WHERE myTable.fkId = @MyFkId;

    UNION

    SELECT mydate AS MyDate, 1 AS DateType
    FROM myTable
    WHERE myTable.fkId = @MyFkId;
) AS myCombinedDateTable
```

This however includes duplicates of the original dates.

> Dec 31, 2009 -  2
>   Jan 1, 2010 -  2
>   Jan 1, 2010 -  1
>   Jan 2, 2010 -  2
>   Jan 2, 2010 -  1
>   Jan 3, 2010 -  2
>   Jan 9, 2010 -  2
>   Jan 10, 2010 -  1
>   Jan 11, 2010 -  2

How can I best remove these duplicates? I am considering a temporary table, but am unsure if that is the best way to do it.

This also appears to me that it may provide performance issues as I am running the same query three separate times.

What would be the best way to handle this request?

Comment: They are not technically duplicates, as the date types are different. Which date type do you want to show when there are duplicates?

Comment: @OrbMan, you are correct, I would like to display Type 1 if the date is repeated and ignore Type 2.

Comment: where does `Jan 1, 2009 - 2` come from ... (notice the jan and 2009).

Comment: @Gaby, fat-fingered, I'll correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have accepted the solution, let me give this solution for the reference:

```
SELECT MyDate, Min(DateType)
From
(
  SELECT MyDate + T1.RecordType AS MyDate, T1.DateType
  FROM
  (
    Select 1 AS RecordType, 2 AS DateType
    Union ALL
    Select 0 AS RecordType, 1 AS DateType
    Union ALL
    Select -1 AS RecordType, 2 AS DateType
  ) AS T1
  CROSS JOIN myTable
  Where myTable.fkId = @MyFkId
) AS CombinedTable
Group By MyDate
```

Advantage of this solution, myTable is queried only once, current case we are having a filter on fkID so right now performance will not matter, but if we have to evaluate complex query then this technique can work fine with respect to Union.

Comment: This looks really good, I'm comparing the efficincy right now. I had to make a couple changes to your code though. I'll update the sample

Comment: Thanks, I've switched the answer over here because the performance is better. The IO reads are about 1/3rd of the other solution and the CPU is consistently less. The duration is rather similar, but your query is always less. Thanks to everyone for their assistance

Answer (score 4):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT MyDate, min(DateType) as DateType
FROM (
    SELECT mydate - 1 AS MyDate, 2 AS DateType
    FROM myTable
    WHERE myTable.fkId = @MyFkId;

    UNION

    SELECT mydate + 1 AS MyDate, 2 AS DateType
    FROM myTable
    WHERE myTable.fkId = @MyFkId;

    UNION ALL

    SELECT mydate AS MyDate, 1 AS DateType
    FROM myTable
    WHERE myTable.fkId = @MyFkId;
) AS myCombinedDateTable
group by MyDate
```

Note: I changed the second `UNION` to a `UNION ALL` for better performance; the last subquery will never have duplicates with the first two subqueries, since `DateType` is always 2 for the first two, and 1 for the last `UNION`ed query.

Comment: props for getting back quicker than me!

Comment: Thanks!! Now I need to look into UNION vs UNION ALL. You learn something new every day.

Comment: For other's not aware of the difference see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all

Answer (score 0):

Tried this and it works. Note my use of DATEADD to get it to work with my local copy of SQL which is SQL2008.

```
SELECT MyDate, Min(DateType)
FROM (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-1,mydate) AS MyDate, 2 AS DateType
    FROM myTable
    WHERE myTable.fkId = @MyFkId

    UNION

    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,mydate) as MyDate, 2 AS DateType
    FROM myTable
    WHERE myTable.fkId = @MyFkId

    UNION

    SELECT mydate AS MyDate, 1 AS DateType
    FROM myTable
    WHERE myTable.fkId = @MyFkId
) AS myCombinedDateTable
group by Mydate
```

Comment: `select getdate() - 1` works fine on my SQL Express 2008, what is the issue you are running into?

Comment: My bad, I defined MyDate as a Date rather than a DateTime. Declare as a Date and SQL2008 chucks an error.  I have a habit these days of only using Date type as I hate dealing with time! :-)