# I need to insert multiple rows at once in sql server ..based on an iterative value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to insert 3 rows at a time in a table based on select statement..

consider the query

```
insert into tblTemp 
(
a,b
)

select a, b from tblTemp2
```

This lets me insert one row in tblTemp..

my requirement is to add 3 rows with iterative values a,a+1,a+2 for each b inserted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a cross join to generate extra rows (via Cartesian product), rather than querying tblTemp2 three times with UNION ALL

```
insert into tblTemp (a, b)
select a + offset, b
from
  tblTemp2
  cross join
  (SELECT 0 AS offset UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2) foo
```

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into tblTemp ( a,b )
select a, b from tblTemp2 UNION ALL
select a+1, b from tblTemp2 UNION ALL
select a+2, b from tblTemp2 UNION ALL
```

Comment: This query is not very efficient as you have to traverse table 3 times, check my response or gbn response. Next two rows are just calculations over the base row. Check this question, it uses the same approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427333/sql-to-get-list-of-dates-as-well-as-days-before-and-after-without-duplicates/2427836#2427836

Answer (score 1):

```
Insert Into tblTemp (a,b)
SELECT T.a + T1.Num , T.B
FROM 
tblTemp2 T
CROSS JOIN
(
 SELECT 0 as Num
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 1 as Num
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 as Num 
) T1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @rbr int
set @rbr=0

while @rbr<3
begin
insert into tblTemp2
select a+@rbr, b from tblTemp2
set @rbr=@rbr+1
end
```