# Get number of rows for tables across all databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Searched a bit and didn't see anything that really fit my needs (although I don't really understand SQL beyond the basic select statement so maybe I just missed it). Took a SQL class in school many moons ago.

I have:

- Virtual Windows Server 2008 R2 running SQL 2008 R2. I connect via MS SQL Server Management Studio
- 90-100 databases
- All DB's have the same table structure (each one is a different client)

I want to:

- Search all databases and return a list of all databases which have a table (TableName) that is larger than say, 5000 records.
- Some sort of script that I can schedule that will use that list and if it finds a DB that the TableName table is more than 5000 records, will delete anything older than x amount of days (say 30). Any kind of logging to know what happened over the last few days would be a bonus.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT/UPDATE (2/24/15): Hiren Dhaduk provided a nice stored procedure that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following store procedure in any database. Then run this store procedure by passing table name and NoOfRows(Minimum number of rows for table , In your case it will be 5000):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_FindLargeTables
@TableName VARCHAR(256) , @NoOfRows int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(256)
    DECLARE @varSQL VARCHAR(512)
    DECLARE @getDBName CURSOR

SET @getDBName = CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE state != 6

CREATE TABLE #TmpTable (TableName VARCHAR(256),
SchemaName VARCHAR(256),
DBName VARCHAR(256))

OPEN @getDBName
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getDBName INTO @DBName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SET @varSQL =  'USE ' + @DBName + ';
    INSERT INTO #TmpTable
    SELECT 
    sysobjects.Name as TableName
    , sysindexes.Rows as NoOfRows , '''+ @DBName + ''' AS DBName
    FROM
    sysobjects
    INNER JOIN sysindexes
    ON sysobjects.id = sysindexes.id
    WHERE
    type = ''U''
    AND sysindexes.IndId < 2 
    and sysobjects.Name = '''+ @TableName +''' and sysindexes.Rows > ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @NoOfRows) + ''

EXEC (@varSQL)
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getDBName INTO @DBName
END
CLOSE @getDBName
DEALLOCATE @getDBName

SELECT *
FROM #TmpTable
WHERE DBName != 'master'

-- STEP 2
DECLARE @DYNAMICQUERY VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @DYNAMICQUERY = 
REPLACE((
SELECT 'DELETE FROM ['+ DBName +'].[dbo].['+ TableName +'] where Createdate   < DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE());'
FROM #TmpTable
WHERE DBName != 'master'
FOR XML PATH('')
), '&lt;' , '<');

EXEC(@DYNAMICQUERY);

DROP TABLE #TmpTable
END
```

> Example : usp_FindLargeTables 'DeltaStuds',5000

Clarification on your second point :

> Unless you run a trace when the changes happen it is not possible.

So to do this i would suggest you to put one column called createdate in this table and then you will be able to delete record created before 30 days.

Comment: Thanks @Hiren Dhaduk, I'll also test this out and report back.

Comment: Ok, Please share if you find something about getting insert date of rows without maintaining a column

Comment: Hi @Hiren Dhaduk, the first query you provided is only for the one DB...not for all DB's. It works, but only for the DB I ran the query against.

Comment: Also, @Hiren Dhaduk, I tried to wrap your first query with a sp_MSforeachdb 'your query' but it returned blank results.

Comment: Might your tables don't have more then 5000 rows.

Comment: I know at least 2 of the databases have DeltaStuds tables that are 150,000+ records. I didn't get those in the list/results of the query. @hiren dhaduk

Comment: I think you should run this query on master database so that it will give you result of all database. Otherwise it will give result based on selected database.

Comment: @llya I just modified my ans. I checked this store procedure in my sql server , it just worked nicely.

Comment: Thanks @hiren dhaduk, I'll give this a try on Monday when I'm back in the office. Appreciate the assistance.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Hiren Dhaduk...looks like that began to work however it failed on a database that was offline. Is there a way to skip any offline databases and only report back against online ones?

lol, sorry for asking for so much help. You guys are the best and know a lot more than me.

Thank you!

Comment: You can use below query to check database status.
SELECT Name, state_desc FROM sys.databases

Comment: @liya I modified my ans by adding filter for offline databases. You can check condition "SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE state != 6" this query will select only online databases.

Comment: Thanks @Hiren Dhaduk. No errors this time, looks like it omitted the offline databases, which is excellent. Results were blank though...and I know I have at least two DB's with huge amounts of records. Just to clarify, I right click on the SP and do 'execute' and then type in the table name and the value...right?

Comment: Yes , Tables which have more then  5000 records but those databases might be offline.

Comment: The ones I'm trying to see are online, but still resulting in a blank result... @Hiren Dhaduk

Comment: As a test, I ran the SP with a value of 1 (instead of 5000) and it still returned a blank results list. @Hiren Dhaduk

Comment: Sorry Liya , I forgot to put dynamic table name in store project. I updated my ans. Modified - http://prntscr.com/60z6hg

Comment: Awesome! That worked! Now I just need to figure out how to delete the data. I would need something like this: DELETE FROM TableName WHERE ChangeDateTime > DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())...if I was to create a job, would it be possible to have your query above as step 1 and then someone be able to have the delete as step 2? @Hiren Dhaduk

Comment: @llya I just edited my ans by adding some lines which will do delete operation in save store procedure. http://prntscr.com/610zty

Comment: Thanks @Hiren Dhaduk...would I be able to split the scripts up and have one that is the original (search for tables) and another one that is just the dynamicquery declaration/statements for the delete? Would the #TmpTable be a variable that can be accessed if I don't drop it in the original query first?

Comment: @llya actually that will not be proper approch to share temp table with two store procedure. You can do that though.

Comment: Okay, I was running into errors with doing them separate so I tried to do them together and got the follwing error: Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ';'. @Hiren Dhaduk

Comment: Put print(@DYNAMICQUERY) instead of EXEC(@DYNAMICQUERY). Let me know which query do you see after running store procedure.

Comment: That worked correctly, I got the result I expected @Hiren Dhaduk

Comment: Do you have any more suggestions on how I can get the stored procedure to delete the contents that are older than X days of the tables returned by your (amazing) query? @Hiren Dhaduk

Comment: http://prntscr.com/631oip - this query will delete past 30 days records for you. I modified store procedure. Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: Hi @Hiren Dhaduk...I'm back to getting the Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ';'. error. This was the initial issue you fixed by having my replace EXEC with PRINT...but PRINT I'm assuming isn't actually deleting anything?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/634kuu - modified it. It should work now. Your table must contain createdate column though.

Comment: slightly different issue. It found the table, but didn't delete it. Got this error: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'DeltaStuds'.

Comment: Delete query don't know that which database to use to delete data. - http://prntscr.com/63yyeo I added use statement in delete query. it should work now. I don't have ready made databases structure so its getting difficult for me to verify query.

Comment: You're getting close @Hiren Dhaduk...it didn't return an error this time. It listed the table that would be affected in the results window but when I run a basic select against that test table, the data is still there...so it didn't actually delete anything.

Comment: Createdate  > DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE()) , This query affect delete query. Are you sure that table contain data older then 30 days ?

Comment: Yes, because when I do a SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE CreateDate > DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE()) it returns a list of records. It just won't delete them using the same where clause. @Hiren Dhaduk

Comment: I don't see any issue with this script. If you can provide remote access of database then i can figure it out.

Comment: Okay, I don't think my manager would allow for that so I'll keep tinkering with it. Thanks for all of your help! @Hiren Dhaduk

Comment: No problem. I will try to generate same senerio in my local machine , will share with you if i find anything.

Comment: Have you had a chance to test it on your local machine @Hiren Dhaduk? I haven't been able to figure out why it isn't actually deleting anything.

Comment: Just tried this in my local environment. I modified store procedure. http://prntscr.com/69a9qw - Remove old store procedure , use latest one that i modified. It worked in my environment.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is very custom to your setup...

You could use the following query to identify tables with `row count greater than 5000`

```
SELECT sc.name +'.'+ ta.name TableName
 FROM sys.tables ta
 INNER JOIN sys.partitions pa
 ON pa.OBJECT_ID = ta.OBJECT_ID
 INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc
 ON ta.schema_id = sc.schema_id
 WHERE ta.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND pa.index_id IN (1,0)
 and ta.name = 'DeltaStuds'
 GROUP BY sc.name,ta.name
 having SUM(pa.rows)>5000
```

But you would need something like this link to run it for all DBs. [How to find column names for all tables in all databases in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729126/how-to-find-column-names-for-all-tables-in-all-databases-in-sql-server). I dont know of a easier way...

For the second part, you will have to setup a delete process that takes the resultset from the above query, creates a dynamic query and deletes rows based on your date field. In that process, you could inject an audit mechanism that logs that delete action, row count, datetime, etc...

Comment: Thanks @SoulTrain. I'll test this out and report back.

Comment: Hey @SoulTrain, I tried to wrap your query with a sp_MSforeachdb 'your query' but it returned blank results. It ran, didn't error, but just returned a bunch of column headings.

Comment: I know at least two databases have a DeltaStuds table that is 150,000+ records (that's why I'm trying to figure this out, so I can run a scheduled process that deletes most if not all of those records as it's causing errors once it gets that large). @SoulTrain