# How can i find out which tables in which databases have a column with a given name in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server 2016 Management Studio, I have multiple databases.

I would like to find out which tables in which databases have a column whose name contains a string. How can i do that?

Is it possible to search within the Object Explorer window?

Comment: maybe query with join sys.objects, sys.all_columns on each database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find column names for all tables in all databases in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729126/how-to-find-column-names-for-all-tables-in-all-databases-in-sql-server)

Comment: Please, please, please read [ask] and try searching before asking yet another question. Also, stop adding "Thanks" to every question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sp_MSForeeachdb`

This approach will gather **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS** for each database on your server

```
Select * Into #TempFields From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where 1=0

Declare @SQL varchar(max)=';Use [?]; Insert Into #TempFields Select * From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS '     
Execute master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb @SQL
Select * from #TempFields
 Where Column_Name Like '%XYZ%'
```

> **EDIT - Requested Commentary**

The First query creates an EMPTY Structure to hold the Information_Schema

Then we DECLARE @SQL which contains the SQL we want to execute for each database.  Notice the **;Use [?];**

Then we simply select the #Temp table for the desired results

Comment: Thanks. Actually I would like to find out which tables in which databases have a column whose name contains a string, instead of a column with a given name.

Comment: @Tim If I understand your requirements, just change the final WHERE  to Where Column_Name like '%XYZ%'

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you add some explanation of what the statements do? I understand the basic SQL commands, but not very sure what the commands in your code do.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to iterate the databases on the server,

```
SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
```

performing the following command for each one, using

```
select table_name,COLUMN_NAME 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
where COLUMN_NAME like '% XXX %'
```

Doing it with a cursor

```
    CREATE TABLE #tmpList (DatabaseName varchar(64),TableName varchar(64))
    DECLARE @DbName varchar(64)
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

    DECLARE @ColCursor  CURSOR


    SET @colCursor = CURSOR FOR
        SELECT [name] FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases

    OPEN @ColCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM @ColCursor INTO @DBName

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO #tmpList '+
                    'SELECT '''+@DbName+''',table_Name FROM '+@dbName+'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where COLUMN_NAME like ''% XXX %'' '
        EXEC(@sql)
        FETCH NEXT FROM @ColCursor INTO @DBName 
    END
    CLOSE @ColCursor;

select * from #tmpList
drop table #tmpList
```

Answer (score 1):

run the following on each database, or using `cursor` and `dynamic sql` for iterating each database

```
select A.name,B.name From sys.objects as A 
inner join sys.all_columns as B
on B.object_id = A.object_id

where A.type = 'U' and B.name = ...
```

**update:**
for fuzzy lookup, use `B.name like '%serarch_pttern%`, `%`means any leading or trailing characters

Comment: Thanks. Actually I would like to find out which tables in which databases have a column whose name contains a string, instead of a column with a given name.

Answer (score 0):

@Tim I agree with John. Here is an example of the code I used yesterday to find out somewhat similar to what your requirement is. This chunk of code will produce a list of tables and columns with that specific string within the data base you choose to run this query on.

```
select 
o.name as [Table_Name]
,c.name as [Column_Name]
,o.create_date as Creation_Date
,o.modify_date as Modify_Date
,o.object_id
,is_nullable
from sys.columns c
inner join sys.objects  o on c.object_id=o.object_id
-- where c.name like '%Discharge_Date%' specific column
where o.name like '%Stg_Shibs%'-- string for example.
order by o.name,c.name
```