# Searching for column title across entire database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to search for a specific column name across an entire SQL DB, and it's unclear how to go about doing that.

Would anyone have advice on the correct syntax?

Comment: https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/index

Comment: Is this a one-time task, or you need to do this repeatedly? If not, you can use SSMS to script your tables and search within the generated script.

Comment: This is a one time query I need to perform

Comment: Also - Red gate doesn't appear to have mac friendly version of the SQL Toolbelt

Comment: just query `sys.columns` or information schema views

Comment: This was a duplicate question, thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2729126/6426692

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the [`sys.columns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) system table and join various other system tables. Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT o.type,
       s.name schema_name,
       o.name object_name,
       c.name column_name
       FROM sys.columns c
            INNER JOIN sys.objects o
                       ON o.object_id = c.object_id
            INNER JOIN sys.schemas s
                       ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
       WHERE c.name = <column name you search for>;
```