# Is there a way in teradata SQL assistant to run a query that provides all the tables and all of their corresponding columns?

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Basically looking for how to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729126/how-to-find-column-names-for-all-tables-in-all-databases-in-sql-server) in Teradata SQL Assistant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following

```
SELECT DatabaseName, TableName, ColumnName
FROM dbc.ColumnsV
```