# Please help me with the equivalent LINQ query for the SQL below,

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

```
SELECT        0 AS GroupId, 'Select All' AS GroupName
UNION
SELECT        GroupId, GroupName
FROM            tbl_AccountGroup
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var lst = context.tbl_AccountGroup.Select(a => new {a.GroupID, a.GroupName})
    .ToList();
lst.Insert(0, new {GroupID = 0, GroupName = "Select All"});
```

Something similar to that may work.. untested. Depending on how your using it there may be better ways.

Comment: Thanks for answering, But It resulting error as - "Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable"

Answer (score 0):

This will do a `UNION ALL`. So that all the values are comming:

```
var result= Enumerable.Range(0,1)
            .Select (s => new {GroupID= 0,GroupName="Select all" })
            .Concat
            (
                db.tbl_AccountGroup
                .Select(a => new {GroupID=a.GroupID, GroupName=a.GroupName})
               .AsEnumerable()
            );
```

Or i don't know if you really want a `UNION`. If you want a `UNION` that means that the values are `distinct` between the statements. Then you have to do like this:

```
var result= Enumerable.Range(0,1)
            .Select (s => new {GroupID= 0,GroupName="Select all" })
            .Union
            (
                db.tbl_AccountGroup
                .Select(a => new {GroupID=a.GroupID,GroupName=a.GroupName})
               .AsEnumerable()
            );
```

See the diffrence between a `UNION` and `UNION ALL` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all)

Comment: Sorry, it resulting the Error :-
The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Union<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: What type is GroupID and GroupName? I mean is GroupID a string(varchar) or an int?

Comment: GroupID- int, GroupName- nvarchar(MAX)