# Support UNION function in BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, union

BigQuery does not seem to have support for UNION yet:
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference

(I don't mean unioning tables together for the source. It has that.)

Is it coming soon?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you want UNION so that you can combine query results, you can use subselects
in BigQuery:

```
SELECT foo, bar 
FROM
  (SELECT integer(id) AS foo, string(title) AS bar 
   FROM publicdata:samples.wikipedia limit 10),
  (SELECT integer(year) AS foo, string(state) AS bar 
   FROM publicdata:samples.natality limit 10);
```

This is almost exactly equivalent to the SQL

```
SELECT id AS foo, title AS bar 
FROM publicdata:samples.wikipedia limit 10
UNION ALL
SELECT year AS foo, state AS bar 
FROM publicdata:samples.natality limit 10;
```

(note that if want SQL UNION and not UNION ALL this won't work)

Alternately, you could run two queries and append the result.

Comment: ahh... very clever. Appending two queries isn't an option in my case, but this construction looks like it should work.

Comment: Just as a note, as you mentioned, this is not exactly a UNION, but rather a UNION ALL [See other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all)

Comment: hello @Jordan-Tigani  if i call the above like query then top records will be of wikipedia and then of natality. I want to know sequence do maintain or not. just want to clerify.

Comment: BigQuery makes no sequencing guarantees unless you use an ORDER BY. So if you use a table union you have no guarantee in which order you'll get results.

Comment: FYI: in sub queries IGNORE CASE at end of all queries not in sub queries. i.e. SELECT bar 
FROM
  (SELECT string(title) AS bar 
   FROM publicdata:samples.wikipedia where title contains 'any' limit 10),
  (SELECT string(state) AS bar 
   FROM publicdata:samples.natality where state contains 'any' limit 10) IGNORE CASE; (GOT ISSUE SO JUST SHARED)

Comment: Guys I am trying to append to a table.. Is that equivalent to UNION answer as mentioned above or will it be an equivalent to UNION ALL that we do in regular SQL..?

Comment: This is equivalent to UNION ALL.

Comment: Running this in GCP BigQuery console, I'm getting "Column name is ambiguous".  If I replace the column names with *, the result concatenates the _columns_, not the _rows_.  Has BigQuery changed the spec?

Answer (score 5):

BigQuery recently added support for [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#union), **including the `UNION` operation**.

---

When submitting a query through the web UI, just make sure to uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" under the SQL Version rubric:
[image]

Comment: What is important though is that you should use UNION with a second keyword:UNION ALL or UNION DISTINCT, see [the following link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#union)

Comment: @RogierWerschkull true dat.

Answer (score 3):

You can always do:

```
SELECT * FROM (query 1), (query 2);
```

It does the same thing as :

```
SELECT * from query1 UNION select * from query 2;
```

Comment: Yes, this works. It's identical to what Jordan posted 2.5 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Note that, if you're using standard SQL, the comma operator now means `JOIN` - [you *have* to use the `UNION` syntax if you want a union](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#comma_operator_with_tables):

> In legacy SQL, the comma operator , has the non-standard meaning of UNION ALL when applied to tables. In standard SQL, the comma operator has the standard meaning of JOIN.

For example:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
    column_name,
    count(*)
from
    (SELECT * FROM me.table1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM me.table2)
group by 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This helped me out very much for doing a UNION INTERSECT with big query's StandardSQL.

```
#standardSQL
WITH
  a AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    table_a),
  b AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    table_b)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  a INTERSECT DISTINCT
SELECT
  *
FROM
  b
```

I STOLE/MODIFIED THIS EXAMPLE FROM:  https://gist.github.com/yancya/bf38d1b60edf972140492e3efd0955d0

Answer (score 0):

Unions are indeed supported. An excerpt from the link that you posted:

**Note:** Unlike many other SQL-based systems, BigQuery uses the comma syntax to indicate table unions, not joins. This means you can run a query over several tables with compatible schemas as follows:

// Find suspicious activity over several days

```
SELECT FORMAT_UTC_USEC(event.timestamp_in_usec) AS time, request_url
  FROM [applogs.events_20120501], [applogs.events_20120502], [applogs.events_20120503]
  WHERE event.username = 'root' AND NOT event.source_ip.is_internal;
```

Comment: That refers to unioning tables together for the source. That's the feature I specifically mentioned as not being what I need.

Comment: Ah I see. I didn't get what you mean by "unioning together for the source" initially. I actually end up doing something similar to what Jordan suggested for a scenario where I need the table names in the result set. I put the table_name in the inner queries and select them from the outer query e.g. SELECT table_name, title, state FROM (SELECT "publicdata:samples.wikipedia" AS table_name, string(title) AS title FROM publicdata:samples.wikipedia limit 10),
 (SELECT "publicdata:samples.natality" AS table_name, string(state) AS state FROM publicdata:samples.natality limit 10)