# Join a table with others two on BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

What I have are 3 tables, one is a huge table, and the other has the reference that I need query the lines.

For example:

```
Table1:        Table2:     Table3:
|value|num|    |value|     |value|
| AAA | 2 |    | AAA |     | BBB |
| BBB | 6 |    | CCC |     | EEE |
| CCC | 3 |
| DDD | 7 |
| EEE | 1 |
```

It should return:

```
|value|num|
| AAA | 2 |
| BBB | 6 |    
| CCC | 3 |
| EEE | 1 |
```

What I need thought that I needed to do is:

```
Select *
from [table1] as A
join [table2] as B
on A.value=B.value
join [table3] as C
on A.value=C.value
```

I am working with the Bigquery, and I do not know if I have any limitation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried executing the query?

Comment: not clear what you want here... values in Table1 that are present in Table2 and Table3?

Comment: SELECT * FROM (query 1), (query 2); This is exactly what i needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are close. But looks like you want an `UNION`

```
Select *
from [table1] as A
   join [table2] as B
   on A.value=B.value
UNION
Select *
from [table1] as A
   join [table3] as C
   on A.value=C.value
```

**EDIT**

looks like bigquery doesnt support [**UNION**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644993/support-union-function-in-bigquery-sql) but have this workaround.

```
SELECT * FROM (query 1), (query 2);
```

It does the same thing as :

```
SELECT * from query1 UNION select * from query 2
```