# Merging tables in Google BigQuery with UNION ALL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to do something like this in BQ. The tables have different schemas. Any ideas how to achieve this?

```
SELECT YYYYMMDDHH, CONTAINER, Parent_Container, PROTOTYPE_ID, Withdrawal_this_hour FROM `tb1`
UNION ALL
SELECT YYYYMMDDHH, CONTAINER, Parent_Container, PROTOTYPE_ID, Refill_this_hour FROM `tb2` 
UNION ALL
SELECT YYYYMMDDHH, CONTAINER, Parent_Container, PROTOTYPE_ID, changes_this_hour, net_amount, date from `tb3`
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: probably will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644993/support-union-function-in-bigquery-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns have to be the same, so something like this:

```
SELECT YYYYMMDDHH, CONTAINER, Parent_Container, PROTOTYPE_ID,
       Withdrawal_this_hour, NULL as Refill_this_hour,
       NULL as changes_this_hour, NULL as net_amount, NULL as date 
FROM `tb1`
UNION ALL
SELECT YYYYMMDDHH, CONTAINER, Parent_Container, PROTOTYPE_ID,
       NULL, Refill_this_hour, NULL, NULL, NULL
FROM `tb2` 
UNION ALL
SELECT YYYYMMDDHH, CONTAINER, Parent_Container, PROTOTYPE_ID,
       NULL, NULL, changes_this_hour, net_amount, date 
FROM `tb3`
```

Answer (score 0):

For union all number of column and their data have to be same for all the tables [big query docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax) you could try like below by using cte

```
  with cte as  (

   SELECT YYYYMMDDHH, CONTAINER, Parent_Container, PROTOTYPE_ID,
   Withdrawal_this_hour, NULL as Refill_this_hour,
   NULL as changes_this_hour, NULL as net_amount, NULL as date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT YYYYMMDDHH, CONTAINER, Parent_Container, PROTOTYPE_ID,
   NULL, Refill_this_hour, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM tb2
   UNION ALL
  SELECT YYYYMMDDHH, CONTAINER, Parent_Container, PROTOTYPE_ID,
   NULL, NULL, changes_this_hour, net_amount, date 
  FROM tb3
 ) select * from cte
```