# mysql union doesn't work as expected

Tags: mysql, union

I had a mysql query :

```
Select count(*) as cnt from  page06 where dl = 1 and TYPE = 'mempage' union 
Select count(*) as cnt from  page06 where err = 1 and TYPE = 'mempage' union  
Select count(*) as cnt from  page06 where dl = 1 and err=1 and TYPE = 'mempage'
```

In most cases `dl` and `err` columns are 0 so two last select will return `0`. I found out this query returns only one  that is not what i expected. I found this solution:

```
Select count(*) as cnt,'s' as p from  page06 where dl = 1 and TYPE = 'mempage' union 
Select count(*),'d' as p  from  page06 where err = 1 and TYPE = 'mempage' union  
Select count(*),'f' as p   from  page06 where dl = 1 and err=1 and TYPE = 'mempage'
```

This query works perfectly but I have written codes in first format. I want to know why this happens and is there any solution (**Except what I said**) to solve this problem?
The reason I don't want to use my solution is I have lots of written queries that I don't want to (or even cannot) change them! what I'm seeking is some king of options to set to connection (like  `set names 'latin1';`)

Comment: `UNION` will discard duplicates from the final result.  Use `UNION ALL` to be sure all rows are returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`

Check this post for a detailed explanation on the difference : 
  [What is the difference between UNION and UNION ALL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all)

```
SELECT count(*) AS cnt FROM  page06 WHERE dl = 1 AND TYPE = 'mempage' UNION ALL
SELECT count(*) AS cnt FROM  page06 WHERE err = 1 AND TYPE = 'mempage' UNION ALL
SELECT count(*) AS cnt FROM  page06 WHERE dl = 1 AND err=1 AND TYPE = 'mempage'
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. Sorry to ask this irrelevant question but do you know a good resource for learning mysql?