# union all with queries that have a different number of columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've run into a case where a sqlite query I'm expecting to return an error is actually succeeding and I was wondering if anyone could point out why this query is valid.

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(
  k INTEGER,
  v INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO test_table( k, v ) VALUES( 4, 5 );

SELECT * FROM(
  SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT k, v FROM test_table WHERE 1 = 0
  )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT rowid, k, v FROM test_table
  )
)
```

[sqlfiddle of above](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/0a28f/2)

I would think that unioning two selects which have a different number of columns would return an error.  If I remove the outermost `SELECT *` then I receive the error I'm expecting: `SELECTs to the left and right of UNION ALL do not have the same number of result columns`.

Comment: Looks like a quirk in SQLite!

Comment: Weird - and what does it return? NULLs for the missing column?

Comment: Oh I checked the demo and it omits the column.

Comment: @Michael : It returns the rowid and k without any third column.

Comment: Why should the query be invalid?

Comment: @Ludo : I would expect it to be invalid since a different number of columns are returned by the select statements being unioned.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, but can you point to the standard that provides a such requirement?

Answer (score 13):

The answer to this seems to be straightforward: **Yes, this is a quirk.**
I'd like to demonstrate this with a short example. But beforehand, let's consult the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound):

> Two or more simple SELECT statements may be connected together to form
>   a compound SELECT using the UNION, UNION ALL, INTERSECT or EXCEPT
>   operator. 
>   In a compound SELECT, all the constituent SELECTs must
>   return the same number of result columns.

So the documentations says very clearly that two `SELECTs` must provide the same number of columns. However, as you said, the outermost `SELECT` strangely avoids this 'limitation'.

**Example 1**

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT k, v FROM test_table
  UNION ALL
    SELECT k, v,rowid FROM test_table
);
```

Result:

```
k|v
4|5
4|5
```

The third column `rowid` gets simply omitted, as pointed out in the comments.

**Example 2**

We are only switching the order of the two select statements.

```
 SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT k, v, rowid FROM test_table
  UNION ALL
     SELECT k, v FROM test_table
  );
```

Result

```
k|v|rowid
4|5|1
4|5|
```

Now, sqlite does not omit the column but add a null value.

**Conclusion**

This brings me to my conclusion, that sqlite simply handles the `UNION ALL` differently if it is processed as a subquery.

PS: If you are just using `UNION` it fails at any scenario.

Answer (score 10):

UNION ALL will return the results with null values in the extra columns.

A basic UNION will fail because UNION without the ALL has to have the same number of columns from both tables.

So:

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table a
UNION ALL 
SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table b
```

returns 3 columns with nulls in column 3.

and:

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table a
UNION 
SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table b
```

should fail because the number of columns do not match.

In conclusion you could add a blank column to the UNION so that you are selecting 3 columns from each table and it would still work.

EX:

```
SELECT column1, column2, '' AS column3 FROM table a
UNION  
SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table b
```

Comment: This answer does not appear to be an accurate description of UNION vs UNION ALL. Based on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all, UNION and UNION ALL are the same except that UNION also does a SELECT DISTINCT on the result. It has nothing to do with the columns

Comment: UNION ALL does *not* accept different column counts.

Answer (score 2):

If your second query has less number of columns, you can do this:

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
from table A

union all

select col1, col2, col3, col4, NULL as col5, 
from table B
```

Instead of `NULL`, one can also use some string constant - `'KPI' as col5`.