# Combining two select statements without on clausule

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables that are not related at all

First table is called `pocetna_baner` that stores 3 pictures that are going to be displayed on index page.

**pocetna_baner** table:

[image: pocetna_baner]

Second table is for blog and I want to take information of 3 blogs ordered by datum desc:

**blog** table

[image: blog]

I tried using UNION, UNION ALL, JOIN without clauses, full outer join, but just cannot get it to work because I never had this situation where there is no **on** clause

[union all with queries that have a different number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704450/union-all-with-queries-that-have-a-different-number-of-columns) -> I searched for answers and got to this one which seemed okay but unfortunately couldn't get it to work

This is what I have by now

```
(SELECT null as blog_id, null as naslov, null as tekst1, null as kategorija, p.ime_slike FROM 
pocetna_baner p )
UNION ALL
(SELECT b.blog_id, b.naslov, b.tekst1, b.kategorija ,null as ime_slike
FROM blog b ORDER BY b.datum DESC LIMIT 3  )
```

And result is this

[image]

My expected output is only to take `b.blog_id, b.naslov, b.tekst1, b.kategorija FROM blog b` ordered by datume desc limit 3 and add column with `ime_slike` from second table

Comment: Union must have same columns.If you want to use Union on different columns then put null value

Comment: If your two tables are completely unrelated, and doesn't contain similar information, you should not be using UNION. Make 2 different queries instead.

Comment: @sultania23 so if I am correct you are suggesting adding collumns to first table that are going to be null in order to match number of collumns in query ?

Comment: Don't add column to table just put their value null at the time of query execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct the ON clause by creating 1 counter column in each table and matching on them:

```
select
  b.blog_id, b.naslov, b.tekst1, b.kategorija, p.ime_slike
from (
  select 
    blog_id, naslov, tekst1, kategorija,
    (@row_number1:=@row_number1 + 1) num
  from blog, (select @row_number1:=0) t 
  order by datum desc limit 3
) b left join (
  select ime_slike,
  (@row_number2:=@row_number2 + 1) num
  from pocetna_baner, (select @row_number2:=0) t
  order by id limit 3
) p on p.num = b.num
```

If you are sure that the `id`s in the table `pocetna_baner` have values 1, 2 and 3 then you can simplify to this:

```
select
  b.blog_id, b.naslov, b.tekst1, b.kategorija, p.ime_slike
from (
  select 
    blog_id, naslov, tekst1, kategorija,
    (@row_number1:=@row_number1 + 1) num
  from blog, (select @row_number1:=0) t 
  order by datum desc limit 3
) b left join pocetna_baner p 
on p.id = b.num
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just given an example by this code.
Please change as per needs.

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
SELECT p.ime_slike,null as blog_id,null as naslov,null as kategorija FROM 
pocetna_baner p 
UNION ALL 
SELECT b.blog_id, b.naslov, b.tekst1, b.kategorija ,null as ime_slike
FROM blog b 
ORDER BY datum DESC LIMIT 3 ) AS k
```