# oracle:Get length of a clob column

Tags: oracle10g

I`m using oracle10g,I have included "dbms_lob.getlength" to get length of a clob column,but it`s failing to fetch and throws error like ->

```
"ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB"
```

Please suggest some answers.

Comment: Sorry,I found the problem of this,there was a "union" keyword being used,so it was the problem,this is fixed by adding "all" like "union all".

Comment: But is `union all` what you realley need ?

Comment: @A.B.Cade:No,i needed "dbms_lob.getlength" to be used to a CLOB column.

Comment: `union all` is not like `union` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/49928/1083652). Are you sure that changing the `union` keyword to `union all` gives you correct results?