# MYSQL Get info from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables. the first contains `customer_group_id` and `account_number`, linking each group to an account. The second contains `customer_id` and `customer_group_id`, linking each customer to a customer group and the third contains customer description by customer ID.

I would like to get customers info for all the customer in the `customer_group` in the account. The syntax I am using is as follows:

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) AS name, cgd.name AS customer_group 
 FROM customer c 
 LEFT JOIN customer_group_description cgd 
 LEFT JOIN customer_group cg 
 ON (c.customer_group_id = cgd.customer_group_id) 
 WHERE cg.account_number = '1'
```

Please, any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
customer_group:
--------------------------------------
| customer_group_id | account_number |
--------------------------------------
| 1                 | 1              |
| 2                 | 1              |
| 3                 | 1              |
--------------------------------------

customer_group_description
--------------------------------------
| customer_group_id | name           |
--------------------------------------
| 1                 | group1         |
| 2                 | group2         |
| 3                 | group3         |
--------------------------------------

customer
-----------------------------------------------
| firstname   | lastname  | customer_group_id |
-----------------------------------------------
| john        | smith     |  1                |
| black       | smith     |  1                |
| gold        | smith     |  2                |
| bob         | dylan     |  3                |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I hope this will help clarify my question better. The idea is to get all the user that are under the account number 1.

Thank you.

Comment: post your tables and some data and wished results and ....

Comment: The table schemas would be most appreciated. Which one is the first table and which one is third?

Comment: from your post don't understand where the problem is. Don't your code work?

Comment: There's no `ON` clause in your first join.

Comment: I added this table schema. Thanks guys

Comment: @OllieJones You are right

Answer (score 1):

Go to MySQL manual for `UNION` and `UNION ALL` and read this Question: [What is the difference between UNION and UNION ALL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all)