# SQL select from 2 tables where 2 condition

Tags: sql, select

I need to get the data according this filter:

The result need to be all content that contain 1 on column2 and column22 from table2.
In this case

Table1 = column2 =  1
Table2 = column22 = 1

```
Table1 = column1, column2, column3
            1       1       2
            2       1       2
            3       1       3
            4       3       3

Table2 = column11, column22, column33
            1           1       0
            2           0       0
            3           0       0
            4           0       0


SELECT * FROM 'Table1' WHERE 'colum2' = 1 AND SELECT * FROM 'Table2' WHERE 'column22'= 1;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what output you require?

Comment: What are your desired results?  Are you joining these 2 tables on column1 and column11?

Comment: I'm sorry, what is the question?

Comment: Learn SQL or hire a developer. This isn't the kind of question that goes "I'm having this problem, I have done some research but found nothing, maybe other people have this problem too". It sounds more like "will you guys do my work for me?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to return the rows from each table that match, then you can use a `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE column2 = 1 
union all
SELECT * 
FROM Table2 
WHERE column22= 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01a02/2)

If you want to return the rows that match both criteria, then possibly you want to JOIN the tables:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
  on t1.column1 = t2.column11
where t1.column2 = 1
  and t2.column22 = 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01a02/6)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Union to eliminate duplicate rows.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1  
WHERE column2 = 1 
union 
SELECT * 
FROM Table2 
WHERE column22= 1;
```

Refer  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all) to understand what is difference between union and union all.