# Select only distinct values from two columns from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

If I have a table such as

```
1 A

1 B

1 A

1 B

2 C

2 C
```

And I want to select distinct from the two columns so that I would get

```
1 

2 

A

B

C
```

How can I word my query? Is the only way to concatenate the columns and wrap them around a distinct function operator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a `union` to create a table of all values from both columns:

```
select  col1 as BothColumns
from    YourTable
union
select  col2
from    YourTable
```

Unlike `union all`, `union` removes duplicates, even if they come from the same side of the `union`.

Comment: @Luv: The outer `distinct` will take care of removing duplicates.  No use forcing a sort operation more than once.

Comment: It worked for me...Also I want to know if I have more than two columns(Say 5 columns).... the 5 queries with union all is working, but is there any optimized method to do it..or I have to do by mentioning 5 queries for 5 columns

Comment: @Andomar : The query plan is same if we remove the outer distinct query and just use `union` in the inner query. I cannot see two sorts.

Comment: @RaviSingh: That would be right, even two distinct operations (like `disinct` and `union`) could probably reuse the same sort.  I'll vote for your answer :)

Comment: but i want two different columns not single column.

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
Select Col1 from YourTable
union
Select Col2 from YourTable
```

`UNION` removes duplicate records (where all columns in the results are the same), `UNION ALL` does not.
Please check [What is the difference between UNION and UNION ALL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all)

For multiple columns, you can go for UNPIVOT.

```
SELECT distinct DistValues
FROM 
   (SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
   FROM YourTable) p
UNPIVOT
   (DistValues FOR Dist IN 
      (Col1, Col2, Col3)
)AS unpvt;
```

Comment: Using `distinct` is not required in first solution.

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49e69/1)

Why even distinct in Union, try this :

```
select cast(id  as char(1)) from test
union
select val from test
```

Comment: Didn't upvote this earlier because of the strange `cast`, but you are right about `union`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      Col1 INT
    , Col2 NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (Col1, Col2)
VALUES (1, 'ab5defg'), (2, 'ae4eii')

SELECT disword = (
    SELECT DISTINCT dt.ch
    FROM (
        SELECT ch = SUBSTRING(t.mtxt, n.number + 1, 1) 
        FROM [master].dbo.spt_values n
        CROSS JOIN (
            SELECT mtxt = (
                SELECT CAST(Col1 AS VARCHAR(10)) + Col2
                FROM @temp
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'
            )
        ) t
        WHERE [type] = N'p'
        AND number <= LEN(mtxt) - 1
    ) dt
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'
)
```

Or try this -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
    a CHAR(1), b CHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (a, b)
VALUES 
    ('1', 'A'), ('1', 'B'), ('1', 'A'),
    ('1', 'B'), ('2', 'C'), ('2', 'C')

SELECT a
FROM @temp

UNION

SELECT b
FROM @temp
```

Comment: For multiple columns (varchar(...)) suitable use XML (see first example) - Col1 + Col2 + ...

Comment: I cannot refrain to say that this answer is impressive - even frightening - by its unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Because what you want select is in different columns, you can use  **union** like below:

```
select distinct tarCol from  
(select distinct column1 as tarCol from table
 union 
select distinct column2 from table) as tarTab
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this to get multiple distinct column values

```
(SELECT DISTINCT `enodeb` as res, 
                 "enodeb" as columnname 
 FROM `raw_metrics`) 
UNION
(SELECT DISTINCT `interval` as res, 
       "interval" as columnname 
 FROM `raw_metrics`)
```