# Get data from two table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on sql server 2008. I want to do something like this.
I have two tables like this.

**`Table1`**

```
Id
1
2
3
4
```

**`Table2`**

```
Id
2
3
5
6
```

**`Output`**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can also be used if you have more than 1 column

```
SELECT coalesce(t1.ID, t2.ID) [Output]
FROM TABLE1 t1
FULL JOIN
TABLE2 t2 ON
t1.id = t2.id
ORDER BY [Output]
```

Answer (score 7):

How about using [UNION](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)

> Combines the results of two or more queries into a single result set
>   that includes all the rows that belong to all queries in the union.
>   The UNION operation is different from using joins that combine columns
>   from two tables.
>
> UNION ALL
>
> Incorporates all rows into the results. This includes duplicates. If
>   not specified, duplicate rows are removed.

```
SELECT Id
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT Id
FROM Table2
```

Have a look at the below demo, which will also show you the difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL`

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/19312/2)

Comment: Perhaps useful to add a note that `union` will filter out duplicates, while `union all` will not.

Comment: @Andomar, I have added a SQL Fiddle DEMO show the difference between UNION and UNION ALL

Comment: I have no idea why this answer wasn't selected..

Comment: @SonerGönül the other answer looks more impressive? X-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [`UNION (Transact-SQL)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)

> Combines the results of two or more queries into a single result set
>   that includes all the rows that belong to all queries in the union.
>   The UNION operation is different from using joins that combine columns
>   from two tables.

```
SELECT Id
FROM Table1

UNION

SELECT Id
FROM Table2
```

*Just a tip*, `UNION` removes all duplicate records, `UNION ALL` doesn't.

Here a [**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/19312/1).

```
| ID |
------
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
```

- [What is the difference between UNION and UNION ALL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using union and Please refer the below link

```
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp
```