# What is the difference between union and union all in mysql?

Tags: mysql, union, union-all

Can anyone please tell me the difference where to use union and where to use uinon all in mysql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all

Comment: Google is really helpful with this type of questions.

Comment: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/10/05/union-vs-union-all-performance/

Comment: There's a manual for this kind of stuff. No research effort shown.

Comment: please check [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all/21275382#21275382)

Answer (score 1):

`UNION` gets `distinct` values, `UNION ALL` doesn't.