# Table scan on internal tables

Tags: oracle

Assume I have 2 tables - TABLE-1 & TABLE-2 and each of the table has 1 million rows with 10 columns and index on col1..

Now I build a internal table on this 2 tables ( 1 + 1 = 2 million) rows,

```
select * from 
(select col1, col2,....col10 from table-1
union all
select col1, col2,....col10 from table-2) x
```

Questions,

```
how will the internal table will be treated in Oracle since its a internal table..
1. Will the internal table will be treated as a table with index on col1?
2. Will this be captured in the Explain plan?
```

Comment: "internal tables" is a bit misleading here. You are simply executing a query. No tables are created, nor are they internal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and yes.

Oracle will effectively treat this inline view as a table.  It can use [predicate pushing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e15858/tgsql_transform.htm#BABDABIF) to apply a filter on the inline view to the base tables, and potentially use an index.  The explain plan will show this.

**Tables, indexes, sample data, and statistics**

```
create table table1(col1 number, col2 number, col3 number, col4 number);
create table table2(col1 number, col2 number, col3 number, col4 number);

create index table1_idx on table1(col1);
create index table2_idx on table2(col1);

insert into table1 select level, level, level, level
from dual connect by level <= 100000;
insert into table2 select level, level, level, level
from dual connect by level <= 100000;

commit;

begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'TABLE1');
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'TABLE2');
end;
/
```

**Explain plan showing predicate pushing and index access**

```
explain plan for
select * from
(
    select col1, col2, col3, col4 from table1
    union all
    select col1, col2, col3, col4 from table2
)
where col1 = 1;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 400235428

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                             | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |            |     2 |    40 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  VIEW                                 |            |     2 |    40 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   UNION-ALL                           |            |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TABLE1     |     1 |    20 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | TABLE1_IDX |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TABLE2     |     1 |    20 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | TABLE2_IDX |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - access("COL1"=1)
   6 - access("COL1"=1)
```

Notice how the predicates happen before the `VIEW`, and both indexes are used.  By default everything should work as well as can be expected.

**Notes**

This type of query structure is called an inline view.  Although a physical table is not built, the phrase "internal tables" is a good way of thinking about how the query logically works.  Ideally, an inline view would work exactly like a pre-built table with the same data.  In reality there are [some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19338530/409172) where things don't quit work that way.  But in general you are definitely on the right path - build a large query by assembling small inline views, and assume that Oracle will optimize it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

for your particular query no any index will be used, but I suppose you do some filtering, ie `where x.col1 = ###`, I'm not sure that oracle will be able to use table-1/table-2 indexes to filter, so I suggest you to put where statements inside "union query"