# Select query for multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, select, join, union

I have tables A01, B01, C01 and so on... all with identical structure.

```
+----+-----+
| ID | val |
+----+-----+
|  1 | a   |
|  2 | b   |
+----+-----+

+----+-----+
| id | val |
+----+-----+
|  1 | c   |
|  2 | d   |
+----+-----+

+----+-----+
| id | val |
+----+-----+
|  1 | e   |
|  2 | f   |
+----+-----+
```

Is it possible to have a query that displays the "val" column from all tables ?

Also so that if a new tables is created the query should not be changed.

I am going to run this on a PHP webpage.

Comment: No. It's not possible. Normalise your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) with [union or union all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all) clause with all your required tables. If you create a table in future , just alter the view to include that table as well.

```
CREATE VIEW AS MYVIEW
SELECT VAL FROM A01 UNION ALL
SELECT VAL FROM B01...
```

Always use same query to get data:

```
SELECT VAL FROM MYVIEW
```

Comment: All answers are good, had to mark yous as best due to vieuw suggestion

Answer (score 1):

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84dc4/13/0)

```
SELECT t1.val
  FROM table1 AS t1
UNION
  SELECT t2.val FROM table2 AS t2
UNION
  SELECT t3.val FROM table3 AS t3
```

Comment: @echo_Me im doing on the way to using UNION, but before i have tried with inner join, then how could it to be same? :(

Answer (score 1):

you cant do new tables in mysql . you must define them . for the given tables you can do this

```
   select val from `A01`
   union all
   select val from `B01`
   union all
   select val from `C01`
```

[**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1298d/1)