# Working SQL Server 2005 Query Optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have two tables **Sell** and **Purchase**. My query is giving me the desired result, I am carefull about it performance so plz guide me if it can be better. My tables are:
     **Table Sell**

```
UserId  | ProductId    |  ProductName   | ProductPrice
1       | p_101        |  Cycle         |   500
1       | p_121        |  Car           |   500000
2       | p_111        |  Cycle         |   5000
```

**Table Purchase**

```
UserId  | ProductId    |  ProductName   | ProductPrice
1       | p_109        |  CellPhone     |   150
2       | p_121        |  Car           |   500000
3       | p_111        |  Book          |   15
```

**Desired OutPut Table**

```
Type    | ProductId    |  ProductName   | ProductPrice
Sell    | p_101        |  Cycle         |   500
Sell    | p_121        |  Car           |   500000
Purchase| p_109        |  CellPhone     |   150
```

**Working Query:**

```
SELECT type, P1.ProductId, P1.ProductName, P1.ProductPrice
     FROM 
        (
         SELECT s.UserId, 'Sell' as type, s.ProductId, s.ProductName, s.ProductPrice FROM [Sell] s
         UNION
         SELECT p.userid, 'Purchase' as type, p.ProductId, p.ProductName, p.ProductPrice FROM [Purchase] p
        ) as P1
     WHERE userid=1
```

Comment: Do you have the query execution plan? Any indexes? Is this ms-sql? This might be better suited for dba.stackexchange.com... Number of rows on those tables?

Comment: Just a thought: Move `WHERE userid=1` to inner Selects

Comment: @rene, nop... i dont have query executation and indexes.

Comment: To see the plan, prefix the query with Explain and execute it. Saying that the only useful indexes are UserId in products and sales seeing as it's the only factor in the where clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better design is to combine both tables and have a transaction_type column which will either have "Purchase" or "Sell" as values. If you do that you won't have to do UNION or UNION ALL.

With current design here is a simple and faster way to get records. Note that I have used UNION ALL which is faster than UNION as UNION uses DISTINCT to unique records which I think in your case doesn't apply. If you provide details about the index and execution plan I can see if there is a better way.

```
SELECT s.userid,
    'Sell' as type,
    s.ProductId, 
    s.ProductName, 
    s.ProductPrice 
FROM Sell s
WHERE UserId = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT p.userid,
    'Purchase' as type,
    p.ProductId, 
    p.ProductName, 
    p.ProductPrice
FROM Purchase P
WHERE UserId = 1
```

Comment: if I run both queries on sql server 2005 and click on "Display Estimated Execution plan", It shows that both query are using 50%,  50% of cpu... with UNION and UNION ALL. but [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all) made me better towards your answer..

Comment: How many records do you have in your table? Do you have a non-unique index on UserId? Also, as I said in the answer above, is it possible to use only 1 table with a transaction_type column?

Comment: 100 to 150 records. and I dont have index on UserId.

Comment: 100 to 150 records might not show the difference but when the table grows UNION ALL will help. You can read more about it at http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/11/sql-server-difference-between-union-vs-union-all-optimal-performance-comparison/ .Also try adding non-unique index to UserId and see if it helps.

Comment: Ya, I read that blog regulary.. got the perfect answer.  Thanx Adarsh.. :)

Answer (score -1):

Its better to use joins rather than subqueries. This way, there will be no overhead on your queries specially on dealing with large volumes of data.

Comment: @Emil Rena: Where can I use the join??

Comment: Presumably there's a users table somewhere, you could join to that. [Adarsh's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20742625/1402923) answer is a better way to go.

Comment: `Its better to use joins rather than subqueries` isn't always true as a general statement. And difficult to see how it applies to the code in the question anyway.

Comment: *JOIN is faster than subquery* is really a myth on real RDBMS(e.g. Oracle, Sql Server, PostgreSQL). MySQL subquery's is utterly slow, hence its join looks fast http://www.ienablemuch.com/2013/08/not-in-is-faster-than-left-join-is-null.html