# SQL Query not returning the correct number from sum()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm currently experimenting with creating a rough ranking/sorting query that will "score" users according to the data that they submit.

Someone with "president" exactly  once in the Role/Position field will be given a score of 100, and anyone with "%vice%" (as in vice president) in the Role/Position field will be scored about half of what is given to those with just "president".

```
SELECT *, sum(relevance)
  FROM (
    SELECT a.*, 
               100 AS relevance 
          FROM application a, 
               document d 
         WHERE d.`Role/Position` LIKE 'president'
               AND d.`AppID` = a.`AppId` 
               AND `AwardID` != 'NULL' 
               AND `Schoolyear` = '2013-2014' 
    UNION 
        SELECT a.*, 
       50 AS relevance 
          FROM application a, 
               document d 
         WHERE d.`Role/Position` LIKE '%vice%'
               AND d.`AppID` = a.`AppId` 
               AND `AwardID` != 'NULL' 
               AND `Schoolyear` = '2013-2014' 
        ) results 
GROUP BY AppID
ORDER BY sum(relevance) DESC
```

My problem is that if I omit the union select portion, I can come up with the total of 200 for someone with two "president" fields. If the union select portion is kept in the query, then relevance only results to 100.

A person with two "president" fields is supposed to have 200 and someone with "%vice%" and "president" will have 150 in their sum(relevance) value supposedly. It also does not go beyond 150 for someone with two "president" and two "%vice%". Could someone point out what I am doing wrong?

I have a lot to learn in regards to SQL and web design, which is why I am asking for help in determining where I've gone wrong in my query. I based my query on this [this guide](http://anthonykinson.co.uk/programing-internet/568_making-mysql-searches-relevant) as a basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UNION` does a `DISTINCT`, which will eliminate duplicate rows. Since you want multiple hits per row in `application` to be possible, [you should use `UNION ALL` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all);

```sql
SELECT *, sum(relevance)
FROM (
  SELECT a.*, 100 AS relevance 
  FROM application a, document d 
  WHERE d.`Role/Position` LIKE 'president' AND d.`AppID` = a.`AppId` 
    AND `AwardID` != 'NULL' AND `Schoolyear` = '2013-2014' 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT a.*, 50 AS relevance 
  FROM application a, document d 
  WHERE d.`Role/Position` LIKE '%vice%' AND d.`AppID` = a.`AppId` 
    AND `AwardID` != 'NULL' AND `Schoolyear` = '2013-2014' 
) results 
GROUP BY AppID
ORDER BY SUM(relevance) DESC
```