# How to add an extra row at end of query with value of (previousRowColA + 1) in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with data and I'm selecting out the "rank":

```
SELECT (@rank:=@rank+1) AS 'value' FROM MYTable a INNER JOIN (SELECT @rank :=0) b
```

This returns:

```
VALUE
1
2
3
4
```

Because there are 4 rows. But I want a query that can return me the results with one extra row (i.e. n+1, where n == totalNumberRows):

```
VALUE
1
2
3
4
5
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Use `union` and select something as value

Comment: @Hardy Thank you, that's correct. See TimBurch's answer below.

Comment: `UNION ALL` is probably better since it has less overhead and you actually want all rows.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson it appears for performance that `UNION ALL` is better, thank you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a UNION query:

```
SELECT (@rank:=@rank+1) AS 'value'
FROM MYTable a
    INNER JOIN (SELECT @rank :=0) b
UNION ALL
SELECT (@rank+1);
```

Comment: Thank you! That's the answer. I will mark it in 11 minutes when Stack lets me.

Comment: But avoid `UNION` when it can be replaced with `UNION ALL` operation. `UNION` causes grouping, `UNION ALL` - doesn't.

Comment: @zealot How would a "UNION ALL" change that query? Would it still work as I want?

Comment: `UNION` is equivalent of `select distinct rows from .. union all ..`

Comment: @zealot OK, so performance is better with `UNION ALL` thank you!

Comment: @zealot Thanks for the reminder about UNION ALL. I've edited my answer accordingly.