# Symfony2 get and sort data from two different tables

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Can somebody help me, to get all data from two tables with different columns? for now it's work, but i want to sort all posts by field "created" order by DESC. 
Now i have sorting by id and then by "created" field.
That's my repository method

```
public function getLatestPosts($limit = null)
{

    $queryTopics = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->getConnection()
        ->prepare('select * from topic order by  created  DESC');

    $queryTopics->execute();
    $topics = $queryTopics->fetchAll();

    $queryDiary = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->getConnection()
        ->prepare('select * from diary order by  created  DESC');

    $queryDiary->execute();
    $diaries = $queryDiary->fetchAll();

    $posts = array_merge($topics, $diaries);



    return $posts;
}
```

schema bd

```
TABLE  `topic` (
      `topic_id` 
      `topic_title`
      `created` 
    )

    TABLE `diary` (
  `id` 
  `title`
  `comment`
  `height` 
  `weight`
  `created`
)
```

Comment: Do both tables have the same number of columns, or can you select an equal subset of columns from each table? I'm thinking you can do a `UNION`/`UNION ALL` on your two tables. If you use that result set as a subquery then you can apply `ORDER BY` on it, and you don't have to do any stitching together or ordering of your result set in PHP at all.

Comment: If you want to update your answer to provide a list of the columns in each table I should be able to post a more concrete answer.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the update. I just posted an answer that makes some assumptions. I can see now that your column count is different - I can update my answer if you can clarify this question: table `diary` has more columns than `topic` so, do you want to select all columns from `diary`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'll post an answer based on some assumptions, because I don't know the exact structure of your tables. You mentioned that the columns were different - this could mean one or all of the following:

- The column titles are different
- The column count is different; i.e: one table has more columns than the other

However, since you are merging these result sets, I assume you are treating them the same - for instance displaying them in a table. So let's assume that both tables either have the same column count, or you can manually SELECT a matching count of each table's columns.

In other words, if you can match the column count, the column names do not matter because you can do a [`UNION` or a `UNION ALL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all).

For example:

```
SELECT id, name, created FROM topics 
UNION 
SELECT id, title, created FROM diary
```

Note that the column titles do not have to match. If you want to apply `ORDER BY` on this result set just use a subquery, and order on that. For example:

```
SELECT posts.* FROM (
    SELECT id, name, created FROM topics 
    UNION 
    SELECT id, title, created FROM diary
) AS posts ORDER BY created DESC;
```

This should allow you to apply the ordering criteria you want, no need for array merging and sorting on the PHP level (which I assume will be a fair bit slower).

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT**

Since I posted this answer, you've edited your question to add some clarification. The number of columns in each table do not match.

In this case you have two options:

1. Explicitly `SELECT` a matching number of columns from each table (remember the names don't have to match, just the count)
2. 'Match' the column count by adding fake 'padding' columns to the `SELECT` query for the table with less columns.

An example of the second option, padding with `NULL`:

```
SELECT 
  topic_id, 
  topic_title, 
  NULL AS comment,
  NULL AS height,
  NULL AS weight,
  created 
FROM topic
UNION
SELECT 
  id, 
  title, 
  comment, 
  height, 
  weight, 
  created 
FROM diary
```

Admittedly, this way is sorta gnarly in my view but it should work for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I think that most easier way to do it is to use [array sorting functions in php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php), it should also be the most fastest way (server time) to do it