# Consultation abount union query in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

i need all the data that in table1 + all the data that in table2

Except what in table2 that As it in table1

I do not know how to explain... so I will detail what i need using tables....

**sample 1
----------**

```
Table1
=====
Name | Age
========
  M     |  1
  M     |  2
  M     |  1

Table2
=====
Name | Age
========
  M     |  1
  M     |  1
  M     |  1 


Result
====

Name | Age
========
  M     |  1
  M     |  2
  M     |  1
```

**sample2
---------**

```
Table1
=====
Name | Age
========
  M     |  1
  M     |  2
  M     |  1

Table2
=====
Name | Age
========
  M     |  1
  M     |  3
  M     |  2 


Result
====

Name | Age
========
  M     |  1
  M     |  1
  M     |  2 
  M     |  3
```

thanks

Comment: Are you also trying to match on a 'row number' per say? If so, how are you sorting the results? Do these tables have a primary key to join with, or sort by, a name, ID, anything?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `UNION` is your best answer, though the way your question is asked, neither union nor union all will give the results you seek.

[What is the difference between UNION and UNION ALL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all)

Comment: `UNION` will in fact give what you are after is you have more data in the tables you are selecting from than given in the example, like a name or ID. Being that was not included in the question, this information would help to better answer your request.