# Breaking one any row in a query into multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, select, multiple-records

I have a table with these columns : a, b1, b2, b3

and I want to get query from this table like this :

```
_______________
| col1 | col2 |
|-------------|
|   a  |  b1  |
|   a  |  b2  |
|   a  |  b3  |
|_____________|
```

is it posible with on SELECT command ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all

Comment: So, you don't care what's the data in your original table?. And is it always the first column the one that it's repeated?

Comment: yes ... but all "b"s are same type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing `UNION ALL` is one way, but you can also use `UNPIVOT` query see below,

Anyway I think UNPIVOT will be more efficient than doing union all multiple times.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/38852)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(col1 VARCHAR(5), col2 VARCHAR(5)
             , Col3 VARCHAR(5), Col4 VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
   ( 'a' , 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'),
   ( 'd' , 'E1', 'E2', 'E3')


SELECT col1 
      ,Vals AS Col2
FROM @TABLE t 
UNPIVOT (Vals FOR N IN (col2,col3,col4) ) up
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/38852/0)**:

```
| COL1 | COL2 |
|------|------|
|    a |   B1 |
|    a |   B2 |
|    a |   B3 |
|    d |   E1 |
|    d |   E2 |
|    d |   E3 |
```

Comment: I understood the question so much different

Comment: @محمد رضا please explain something to me. How were you able to determine - within 47 seconds of this answer even appearing on the page - that it solved your problem? How were you able to even read it that quickly, never mind test that it solved the issue on *your* test data?

Comment: Yea it is a bit confusing, at one point I thought OP is saying that all this `a, b1, b2, b3` is in one column :)

Comment: good question @AaronBertrand lol, Anyway I think this SQL FIDDLE OUTPUT is really a cool feature.

Comment: I thought that the question says that he has 4 columns, `a, b1, b2, b3`, that's why I don't see how this solves his problem

Comment: It did, @Lamak.  It would be clearer if there was a 'COL_1_5' that holds the original b1-b2-b3 names.  Here's the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/38854) to show what I mean.