# Counting from 2 columns in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In essence I have one table with two columns

```
One    Two    
-----------
A       B   
B       C    
C       D
```

and I want to count the number of A's through D.

Resulting

```
Letter    Count  
---------------
   A        1
   B        2  
   C        2   
   D        1
```

My code now is

```
Select one, count("") from table   
group by one   
union    
Select two, count("*") from table  
group by two
```

Right now I am getting

```
Letter    Count  
---------------
   A        1
   B        1  
   B        1  
   C        1  
   C        1  
   D        1
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT Count(a), 
       a 
FROM  (SELECT cola a 
       FROM   table 
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT colb a 
       FROM   table) c 
GROUP  BY a
```

Comment: Not sure why anyone would vote this down as it's a correct solution.

Comment: @Pradeeep you can use UNION instead of UNION ALL Bcoz UNION is much more efficient than UNION ALL.

Comment: @Hardik union will remove duplicates that should not be done here bud!!

Comment: If I want to save it as a new table?   Create Table (name) insert into (name) From (SQL Query) doesnt work.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @bropedope - Simple way is **select count(a),a into newtable from (select ..) group by a**

Comment: @Hardik `union all`is typically faster as it does not have to remove duplicates.

Comment: @jpw union all is slower then UNION. I have read alot of articals related to this. if you want you can check with the execution plan for this Please refer this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all

Comment: @Hardik - From your link it is very clear that UNION ALL much Faster than UNION!!!!! Union has to sort the records first then it has to remove duplicates. sort is a costlier operation.

Comment: @Hardik I think you should read the article you linked again. It clearly says that `union all` is faster than `union` just like I said. The execution plan shows that`union`will use a costly sort or merge join to exclude duplicates which `union all` won't have to do.

Answer (score 1):

there is no reason to group twice.

```
select letter, count(*) as total_cnt
from 
(
Select one as letter from table
union all
Select two as letter from table
) 
group by letter;
```

Comment: @bropedope It's actually incorrect as `union`without`all`eliminates duplicates.

Comment: @jpw Never knew that!

Answer (score 1):

```
select letter, sum(total) from
(
Select one as letter, count(1) as total from tablename
group by one
union all
Select two as letter, count(1) as total from tablename
group by two) as t1
group by t1.letter 
order by t1.letter asc
```

Answer (score 0):

***You can do this***

`SELECT LETTER,
    count(*) AS _count
FROM (
    SELECT One AS Letter
    FROM Test
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Two AS Letter
    FROM Test
    ) T1
GROUP BY LETTER`