# mysql union of 2 tables

Tags: mysql, union

I have 2 tables:

```
table A (id, user_id, flag)

table B (id, user_id, flag)
```

Here If I take Count of table A it comes as 10 and that of B 5

So Total = 10 + 5 = 15.

```
SELECT * FROM table A
LEFT JOIN table B ON table B.user_id = table A.user_id
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table A
RIGHT JOIN table B ON table B.user_id = table A.user_id
```

So It should Come 15 instead it showing 50.

Comment: Plz add the data of the tables.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 UNION 
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
```

UNION removes duplicate records in other hand UNION ALL does not.Check [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all)

Comment: My Scenario is like i want Full outer join concept which is not possible i guesss

Comment: In your code , replace UNION ALL -> UNION , check what output u get

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the data in your tables are correct.

**Table A Should have 15 rows**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as 'rowCountTableA' FROM table_a;
```

**Table B Should have 5 rows**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as 'rowCountTableB' FROM table_b;
```

If your tables are correct and have exactly matching column names you can join them together by specifying asterisks to get all column values.

If however the columns in your table have a few different column names that are in table_a that are not in table_b you must call out the column names instead of using asterisk to get all values.

EXAMPLE:

```
SELECT (id,user_id,flag) FROM table_a
UNION ALL
SELECT (id,user_id,flag) FROM table_b
```