# Records gone after inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join, sum

Got some problem after using inner join, this is my query.

```
select sum(total)  as total,id
from
(
select * from midsemester union
select * from endsemester
) as vij
group by id
```

This is the table:

**Table name: midsemester**

```
ID  Grade
----------
1    10
2    30
3    40
```

**Table name: endsemester**

```
ID   Grade
----------
1    30
2    40
3    20
```

and i need to sum these table to new table called total. This is the results that i was hoping.

**Table name: total**

```
ID   Grade
----------
1     40
2     70
3     60
```

I actually just need to sums up the grade's value using the id for the 3rd table. And tried several times using inner join, it's working. But when i re-checked the 3rd table again, the record was empty. Would appreciate any help, thanks! :)

Comment: You need to union all.


Check:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all

Comment: I saw it before posting this question and tried using union all, but it's still the same. Anyway, thanks man :)

Comment: I would recommend not having two different tables that store the same thing. You should combine `midsemester` and `endsemester` into one grade-related table and introduce a column that indicates which part of the semester the grade is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
insert into total(ID,Grade) select midsemester.ID,(midsemester.grade+endsemester.grade)as total from midsemester
inner join endsemester
on midsemester.ID=endsemster.ID
```

Use order by ID if u want data according to ID increasing order

Comment: @sunstation :ok it was Glad for me to help u

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO total (Id, Grade)
SELECT id, SUM(grade) AS total
FROM (SELECT id, grade FROM midsemester 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT id, grade FROM endsemester
     ) AS vij
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: yours was summing the entire field my friend, what i need is to sum it up one by one. But anyway thanks for helping :)

Comment: i need each record get summed, not entirely. Please see the 3rd table on my post. That's what i really wants for the result. No offense, but when i use your query the result was like this: ID = 12, and the Grade = 60

Comment: Oh my bad. I'm really sorry about the misunderstanding, so i need to join the midsemester and endsemester grades and put it on the total table. And it seems like when i use some other query it's not inserting to the 3rd tables.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
select a.id,(a.grade+b.grade) as sum 
into total
from midsemester a 
left join endsemester b 
    on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: How do i put this on the 3rd table? it's not inserted to the records bro.

Comment: create tabel total (id integer , Grade integer);               insert into total select a.id,(a.grade+b.grade) as sum from midsemester a 
left join endsemester b 
    on a.id = b.id;